# How can I set a dark theme in TeXstudio?

Tags: texmaker, texstudio

After perusing [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides), I'm considering switching from TeXmaker (in which I use the preset "dark theme") to its fork, TeXstudio.

What I mean by "dark theme" is a dark background with suitable text colours, which, in my experience, is easier on the eyes than a bright background is. Here is an example:

[image]

TeXstudio doesn't seem to offer any preset dark theme, though, which means I have to customise all the colours/syntax-highlighting settings from scratch to get a dark theme even remotely usable. This can prove very time-consuming.

I'm aware this might sound a bit cheeky but,

1. if you are a long-time TeXstudio user, and
2. you have fine-tuned the editor colours to get a visually pleasant dark theme,

please consider posting the relevant lines from your settings (`.txsprofile` or `.tmxprofile`) file as an answer below.

TeXstudio users who would like to use a dark theme could then build on your settings to fine-tune their own.

Comment: Could you use the [Solarized Dark](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) `.tmTheme` or port it to `.texsprofile`?

Comment: I am tempted to ask the same question for WinEDT!

Comment: dark themes are not good for the eyes. Makes double vision and can affect eye health. Best is white background or some bright close to white with dark/black for text. Just like here on this forum.

Comment: @Nasser Source? I like my dark theme just fine.

Comment: You must have good eyes. Good for you. But as you can see, all popular sites have white background and dark text vs. the other way around, since it is easier for the eyes for most people. May be age has something to do with it, I do not know.

Comment: @Nasser The results of the recent Stack-Overflow survey is of interest, here: http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech-ide

Comment: Developed for long time with white background, I can say dark is the best for relax the eyes

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Since version 3 there is a built-in dark mode. You can enable it by opening the settings (*Options* → *Configure TeXstudio...*) and selecting *Adwaita Dark (txs)* as the *Style* in the *General* tab.

[image]

You will have to click *OK* for the setting to take effect.

Comment: It only took them seven years!

Comment: @jub0bs Yeah, good things take time, I guess. :-) Also: Could you consider making this the accepted answer? This question is the first result on of the Google search for "TeXstudio dark mode" and I know people who still mess around in their settings files because they don't realize that that's not necessary anymore.

Comment: Finally!!!!!! Notice that I do not see Adwaita Dark. I see Orion Dark. Maybe because I'm using Linux/Ubuntu?

Answer (score 75):

After some trial & error, I've come up with the following dark theme for TeXstudio, using (mainly) colours from the [Solarized colour palette](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized); thanks to @Holene for recommending the latter to me.

[image]

I'm conscious this kind of tweaks is very much a matter of taste, and may not appeal to anybody else than me. However, my colour settings might be helpful to someone who wants to set up a dark theme in TeXstudio. Therefore, I've decided to post them as an answer; see below.

To apply those setting, substitute the following code for the code currently under the "[formats]" heading in your TeXstudio settings file (.txsprofile); then load that settings file in TeXstudio. You will have to restart TeXstudio for the changed to be effective.

**Edit**: (shameless plug!) Incidentally, I've released a tiny package, called `xcolor-solarized`, that simply defines the 16 colors from Ethan Schoonover's popular [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) color palette, for use in documents typeset with LaTeX & friends. It has been released on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor-solarized); development takes place on [GitHub](https://github.com/Jubobs/xcolor-solarized/).

```
[formats]
version=1.0
data\normal\priority=-1
data\normal\bold=false
data\normal\italic=false
data\normal\overline=false
data\normal\underline=false
data\normal\strikeout=false
data\normal\waveUnderline=false
data\normal\foreground=#839496
data\normal\fontFamily=
data\normal\pointSize=0
data\background\priority=-1
data\background\bold=false
data\background\italic=false
data\background\overline=false
data\background\underline=false
data\background\strikeout=false
data\background\waveUnderline=false
data\background\background=#002b36
data\background\fontFamily=
data\background\pointSize=0
data\commentTodo\priority=-1
data\commentTodo\bold=false
data\commentTodo\italic=false
data\commentTodo\overline=false
data\commentTodo\underline=false
data\commentTodo\strikeout=false
data\commentTodo\waveUnderline=false
data\commentTodo\foreground=#6c71c4
data\commentTodo\fontFamily=
data\commentTodo\pointSize=0
data\comment\priority=-1
data\comment\bold=false
data\comment\italic=false
data\comment\overline=false
data\comment\underline=false
data\comment\strikeout=false
data\comment\waveUnderline=false
data\comment\foreground=#586e75
data\comment\fontFamily=
data\comment\pointSize=0
data\keyword\priority=-1
data\keyword\bold=false
data\keyword\italic=false
data\keyword\overline=false
data\keyword\underline=false
data\keyword\strikeout=false
data\keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\keyword\foreground=#cb4b16
data\keyword\fontFamily=
data\keyword\pointSize=0
data\extra-keyword\priority=-1
data\extra-keyword\bold=true
data\extra-keyword\italic=false
data\extra-keyword\overline=false
data\extra-keyword\underline=false
data\extra-keyword\strikeout=false
data\extra-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\extra-keyword\foreground=#859900
data\extra-keyword\fontFamily=
data\extra-keyword\pointSize=0
data\math-keyword\priority=-1
data\math-keyword\bold=false
data\math-keyword\italic=false
data\math-keyword\overline=false
data\math-keyword\underline=false
data\math-keyword\strikeout=false
data\math-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\math-keyword\foreground=#268bd2
data\math-keyword\fontFamily=
data\math-keyword\pointSize=0
data\link\priority=-1
data\link\bold=false
data\link\italic=false
data\link\overline=false
data\link\underline=true
data\link\strikeout=false
data\link\waveUnderline=false
data\link\fontFamily=
data\link\pointSize=0
data\align-ampersand\priority=-1
data\align-ampersand\bold=true
data\align-ampersand\italic=false
data\align-ampersand\overline=false
data\align-ampersand\underline=false
data\align-ampersand\strikeout=false
data\align-ampersand\waveUnderline=false
data\align-ampersand\foreground=#dc322f
data\align-ampersand\fontFamily=
data\align-ampersand\pointSize=0
data\verbatim\priority=-1
data\verbatim\bold=false
data\verbatim\italic=false
data\verbatim\overline=false
data\verbatim\underline=false
data\verbatim\strikeout=false
data\verbatim\waveUnderline=false
data\verbatim\fontFamily=
data\verbatim\pointSize=0
data\sweave\priority=-1
data\sweave\bold=false
data\sweave\italic=false
data\sweave\overline=false
data\sweave\underline=false
data\sweave\strikeout=false
data\sweave\waveUnderline=false
data\sweave\fontFamily=
data\sweave\pointSize=0
data\picture\priority=-1
data\picture\bold=false
data\picture\italic=false
data\picture\overline=false
data\picture\underline=false
data\picture\strikeout=false
data\picture\waveUnderline=false
data\picture\foreground=#c93682
data\picture\fontFamily=
data\picture\pointSize=0
data\numbers\priority=-1
data\numbers\bold=false
data\numbers\italic=false
data\numbers\overline=false
data\numbers\underline=false
data\numbers\strikeout=false
data\numbers\waveUnderline=false
data\numbers\foreground=#2aa198
data\numbers\fontFamily=
data\numbers\pointSize=0
data\math-delimiter\priority=-1
data\math-delimiter\bold=true
data\math-delimiter\italic=false
data\math-delimiter\overline=false
data\math-delimiter\underline=false
data\math-delimiter\strikeout=false
data\math-delimiter\waveUnderline=false
data\math-delimiter\foreground=#399900
data\math-delimiter\fontFamily=
data\math-delimiter\pointSize=0
data\text\priority=-1
data\text\bold=false
data\text\italic=false
data\text\overline=false
data\text\underline=false
data\text\strikeout=false
data\text\waveUnderline=false
data\text\fontFamily=
data\text\pointSize=0
data\escapeseq\priority=-1
data\escapeseq\bold=false
data\escapeseq\italic=false
data\escapeseq\overline=false
data\escapeseq\underline=false
data\escapeseq\strikeout=false
data\escapeseq\waveUnderline=false
data\escapeseq\fontFamily=
data\escapeseq\pointSize=0
data\latexSyntaxMistake\priority=-1
data\latexSyntaxMistake\bold=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\italic=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\overline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\underline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\strikeout=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\waveUnderline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\fontFamily=
data\latexSyntaxMistake\pointSize=0
data\environment\priority=-1
data\environment\bold=false
data\environment\italic=false
data\environment\overline=false
data\environment\underline=false
data\environment\strikeout=false
data\environment\waveUnderline=false
data\environment\foreground=#b58900
data\environment\fontFamily=
data\environment\pointSize=0
data\structure\priority=-1
data\structure\bold=true
data\structure\italic=false
data\structure\overline=false
data\structure\underline=false
data\structure\strikeout=false
data\structure\waveUnderline=false
data\structure\fontFamily=
data\structure\pointSize=0
data\current\priority=-1
data\current\bold=false
data\current\italic=false
data\current\overline=false
data\current\underline=false
data\current\strikeout=false
data\current\waveUnderline=false
data\current\background=#073642
data\current\fontFamily=
data\current\pointSize=0
```

Comment: Nice color scheme. How do I get to the TeXstudio settings file?

Comment: Linux users might have to do [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179805/31839) to load their colours, instead of editing the `.txsprofile`

Comment: This should be distributed with texStudio.

Comment: @k-dubs Check out this [FAQ page](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/) (look for "Setting file" on this page). Note that when TeXstudio is open, the setting file `texstudio.ini` may not appear in the file manager.

Comment: OK, this changes the editor window, but what about the other windows and toolbars?

Comment: @skan - see https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/45

Comment: my, my this is beautiful!. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 50):

I know this is an old post but I have been using home-brewed Solarized Dark/Light themes and I am willing to share with the hope that somebody will find them useful.

Highlighting schemes for dtx/Sweave/Pweave/Asymptote/Lua/QtScript editing are also included, though I rarely use them so there may be some inconsistencies. Both themes are tested with current version (2.12.0) of TeXstudio.

Don't forget to make a copy of your current highlighting scheme in case you want to switch back later.

Due to the limit on characters count I am unable to post the entire `[formats]` sections here, they can be found in [my GitHub](https://github.com/Francis-Hsu/TeXstudio_Solarized).

**01/24/2017 Update**: Tweaks for newest version (2.12.0).

---

### Solarized Dark

[image]

---

### Solarized Light

[image]

Comment: @Francis since there is a limit on the character count why don't you put the file somewhere (perhaps Google Drive, dropbox etc...) and paste the link here. I think this will be an option to consider.

Comment: @evansdoe: good idea. Moved to GitHub.

Comment: @Davïd: I made some minor changes to the themes and moved them to GitHub. Should be easier to copy now.

Comment: @Francis: But where is the link to the file on github.com?

Comment: @evansdoe: I moved the link to top of the post, is it visible?

Comment: @Francis Can I ask how to use the file you posted in Github?

Comment: @ChuanChen: save your current setting to a `.txsprofile` file, edit it by replacing the `[formats]` section I posted, then load the file.

Comment: @Francis Can I ask how to save the current setting? thanks!

Comment: @ChuanChen: `Options`->`Save Profile...`

Answer (score 47):

The following theme is roughly oriented at [**thinkpixellab's Flatland Theme**](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/flatland) for Sublime Text.

Updated for **TeXstudio 2.11.2** in November 2016.

[image]

```
[formats]
version=1.0
data\normal\priority=-1
data\normal\bold=false
data\normal\italic=false
data\normal\overline=false
data\normal\underline=false
data\normal\strikeout=false
data\normal\waveUnderline=false
data\normal\foreground=#eaeaea
data\normal\fontFamily=
data\normal\pointSize=0
data\normal\wrapAround=false
data\background\priority=-1
data\background\bold=false
data\background\italic=false
data\background\overline=false
data\background\underline=false
data\background\strikeout=false
data\background\waveUnderline=false
data\background\background=#26292c
data\background\fontFamily=
data\background\pointSize=0
data\background\wrapAround=false
data\line%3Aerror\priority=-1
data\line%3Aerror\bold=true
data\line%3Aerror\italic=true
data\line%3Aerror\overline=false
data\line%3Aerror\underline=false
data\line%3Aerror\strikeout=false
data\line%3Aerror\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Aerror\background=#767f85
data\line%3Aerror\fontFamily=
data\line%3Aerror\pointSize=0
data\line%3Aerror\wrapAround=false
data\line%3Awarning\priority=-1
data\line%3Awarning\bold=true
data\line%3Awarning\italic=true
data\line%3Awarning\overline=false
data\line%3Awarning\underline=false
data\line%3Awarning\strikeout=false
data\line%3Awarning\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Awarning\background=#767f85
data\line%3Awarning\fontFamily=
data\line%3Awarning\pointSize=0
data\line%3Awarning\wrapAround=false
data\line%3Abadbox\priority=-1
data\line%3Abadbox\bold=false
data\line%3Abadbox\italic=false
data\line%3Abadbox\overline=false
data\line%3Abadbox\underline=false
data\line%3Abadbox\strikeout=false
data\line%3Abadbox\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Abadbox\background=#767f85
data\line%3Abadbox\fontFamily=
data\line%3Abadbox\pointSize=0
data\line%3Abadbox\wrapAround=false
data\magicComment\priority=-1
data\magicComment\bold=false
data\magicComment\italic=false
data\magicComment\overline=false
data\magicComment\underline=false
data\magicComment\strikeout=false
data\magicComment\waveUnderline=false
data\magicComment\foreground=#9fabb0
data\magicComment\fontFamily=
data\magicComment\pointSize=0
data\magicComment\wrapAround=false
data\commentTodo\priority=-1
data\commentTodo\bold=false
data\commentTodo\italic=false
data\commentTodo\overline=false
data\commentTodo\underline=false
data\commentTodo\strikeout=false
data\commentTodo\waveUnderline=false
data\commentTodo\foreground=#ffffef
data\commentTodo\background=#5f7f5f
data\commentTodo\fontFamily=
data\commentTodo\pointSize=0
data\commentTodo\wrapAround=false
data\comment\priority=-1
data\comment\bold=false
data\comment\italic=false
data\comment\overline=false
data\comment\underline=false
data\comment\strikeout=false
data\comment\waveUnderline=false
data\comment\foreground=#767f85
data\comment\fontFamily=
data\comment\pointSize=0
data\comment\wrapAround=false
data\keyword\priority=-1
data\keyword\bold=true
data\keyword\italic=false
data\keyword\overline=false
data\keyword\underline=false
data\keyword\strikeout=false
data\keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\keyword\foreground=#d88746
data\keyword\fontFamily=
data\keyword\pointSize=0
data\keyword\wrapAround=false
data\extra-keyword\priority=-1
data\extra-keyword\bold=true
data\extra-keyword\italic=false
data\extra-keyword\overline=false
data\extra-keyword\underline=false
data\extra-keyword\strikeout=false
data\extra-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\extra-keyword\foreground=#ffb454
data\extra-keyword\fontFamily=
data\extra-keyword\pointSize=0
data\extra-keyword\wrapAround=false
data\math-keyword\priority=-1
data\math-keyword\bold=true
data\math-keyword\italic=false
data\math-keyword\overline=false
data\math-keyword\underline=false
data\math-keyword\strikeout=false
data\math-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\math-keyword\foreground=#b7d877
data\math-keyword\fontFamily=
data\math-keyword\pointSize=0
data\math-keyword\wrapAround=false
data\link\priority=-1
data\link\bold=false
data\link\italic=false
data\link\overline=false
data\link\underline=true
data\link\strikeout=false
data\link\waveUnderline=false
data\link\fontFamily=
data\link\pointSize=0
data\link\wrapAround=false
data\align-ampersand\priority=-1
data\align-ampersand\bold=true
data\align-ampersand\italic=false
data\align-ampersand\overline=false
data\align-ampersand\underline=false
data\align-ampersand\strikeout=false
data\align-ampersand\waveUnderline=false
data\align-ampersand\foreground=#b5d1df
data\align-ampersand\fontFamily=
data\align-ampersand\pointSize=0
data\align-ampersand\wrapAround=false
data\verbatim\priority=-1
data\verbatim\bold=false
data\verbatim\italic=false
data\verbatim\overline=false
data\verbatim\underline=false
data\verbatim\strikeout=false
data\verbatim\waveUnderline=false
data\verbatim\fontFamily=
data\verbatim\pointSize=0
data\verbatim\wrapAround=false
data\picture\priority=-1
data\picture\bold=false
data\picture\italic=false
data\picture\overline=false
data\picture\underline=false
data\picture\strikeout=false
data\picture\waveUnderline=false
data\picture\foreground=#ece8c4
data\picture\fontFamily=
data\picture\pointSize=0
data\picture\wrapAround=false
data\picture-keyword\priority=-1
data\picture-keyword\bold=false
data\picture-keyword\italic=false
data\picture-keyword\overline=false
data\picture-keyword\underline=false
data\picture-keyword\strikeout=false
data\picture-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\picture-keyword\foreground=#ffb454
data\picture-keyword\fontFamily=
data\picture-keyword\pointSize=0
data\picture-keyword\wrapAround=false
data\braceMatch\priority=-1
data\braceMatch\bold=true
data\braceMatch\italic=false
data\braceMatch\overline=false
data\braceMatch\underline=false
data\braceMatch\strikeout=false
data\braceMatch\waveUnderline=false
data\braceMatch\foreground=#b5d1df
data\braceMatch\background=#2b2b2b
data\braceMatch\fontFamily=
data\braceMatch\pointSize=0
data\braceMatch\wrapAround=false
data\braceMismatch\priority=-1
data\braceMismatch\bold=true
data\braceMismatch\italic=false
data\braceMismatch\overline=false
data\braceMismatch\underline=false
data\braceMismatch\strikeout=false
data\braceMismatch\waveUnderline=false
data\braceMismatch\foreground=#2b2b2b
data\braceMismatch\background=#b5d1df
data\braceMismatch\fontFamily=
data\braceMismatch\pointSize=0
data\braceMismatch\wrapAround=false
data\search\priority=-1
data\search\bold=false
data\search\italic=false
data\search\overline=false
data\search\underline=false
data\search\strikeout=false
data\search\waveUnderline=false
data\search\foreground=#000000
data\search\background=#ffb454
data\search\fontFamily=
data\search\pointSize=0
data\search\wrapAround=false
data\numbers\priority=-1
data\numbers\bold=false
data\numbers\italic=false
data\numbers\overline=false
data\numbers\underline=false
data\numbers\strikeout=false
data\numbers\waveUnderline=false
data\numbers\foreground=#b7d877
data\numbers\fontFamily=
data\numbers\pointSize=0
data\numbers\wrapAround=false
data\math-delimiter\priority=-1
data\math-delimiter\bold=true
data\math-delimiter\italic=false
data\math-delimiter\overline=false
data\math-delimiter\underline=false
data\math-delimiter\strikeout=false
data\math-delimiter\waveUnderline=false
data\math-delimiter\foreground=#72aaca
data\math-delimiter\fontFamily=
data\math-delimiter\pointSize=0
data\math-delimiter\wrapAround=false
data\text\priority=-1
data\text\bold=false
data\text\italic=false
data\text\overline=false
data\text\underline=false
data\text\strikeout=false
data\text\waveUnderline=false
data\text\foreground=#b7d877
data\text\fontFamily=
data\text\pointSize=0
data\text\wrapAround=false
data\escapeseq\priority=-1
data\escapeseq\bold=false
data\escapeseq\italic=false
data\escapeseq\overline=false
data\escapeseq\underline=false
data\escapeseq\strikeout=false
data\escapeseq\waveUnderline=false
data\escapeseq\fontFamily=
data\escapeseq\pointSize=0
data\escapeseq\wrapAround=false
data\spellingMistake\priority=-1
data\spellingMistake\bold=false
data\spellingMistake\italic=false
data\spellingMistake\overline=false
data\spellingMistake\underline=false
data\spellingMistake\strikeout=false
data\spellingMistake\waveUnderline=true
data\spellingMistake\linescolor=#dfaf8f
data\spellingMistake\fontFamily=
data\spellingMistake\pointSize=0
data\spellingMistake\wrapAround=false
data\wordRepetition\priority=-1
data\wordRepetition\bold=false
data\wordRepetition\italic=false
data\wordRepetition\overline=false
data\wordRepetition\underline=false
data\wordRepetition\strikeout=false
data\wordRepetition\waveUnderline=true
data\wordRepetition\linescolor=#dc8cc3
data\wordRepetition\fontFamily=
data\wordRepetition\pointSize=0
data\wordRepetition\wrapAround=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\priority=-1
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\bold=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\italic=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\overline=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\underline=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\strikeout=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\waveUnderline=true
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\linescolor=#dc8cc3
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\fontFamily=
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\pointSize=0
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\wrapAround=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\priority=-1
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\bold=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\italic=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\overline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\underline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\waveUnderline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\fontFamily=
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\wrapAround=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\priority=-1
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\bold=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\italic=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\overline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\underline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\waveUnderline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\fontFamily=
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\wrapAround=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\priority=-1
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\bold=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\italic=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\overline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\underline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\waveUnderline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\fontFamily=
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\wrapAround=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\priority=-1
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\bold=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\italic=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\overline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\underline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\waveUnderline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\fontFamily=
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\wrapAround=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\priority=-1
data\latexSyntaxMistake\bold=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\italic=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\overline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\underline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\strikeout=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\waveUnderline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\linescolor=#dfaf8f
data\latexSyntaxMistake\fontFamily=
data\latexSyntaxMistake\pointSize=0
data\latexSyntaxMistake\wrapAround=false
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\priority=-1
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\bold=false
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\italic=true
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\overline=false
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\underline=false
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\strikeout=false
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\waveUnderline=false
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\foreground=#94af64
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\fontFamily=
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\pointSize=0
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\wrapAround=false
data\environment\priority=-1
data\environment\bold=false
data\environment\italic=false
data\environment\overline=false
data\environment\underline=false
data\environment\strikeout=false
data\environment\waveUnderline=false
data\environment\foreground=#d88746
data\environment\fontFamily=
data\environment\pointSize=0
data\environment\wrapAround=false
data\referencePresent\priority=-1
data\referencePresent\bold=true
data\referencePresent\italic=false
data\referencePresent\overline=false
data\referencePresent\underline=false
data\referencePresent\strikeout=false
data\referencePresent\waveUnderline=false
data\referencePresent\foreground=#b5d1df
data\referencePresent\fontFamily=
data\referencePresent\pointSize=0
data\referencePresent\wrapAround=false
data\referenceMissing\priority=-1
data\referenceMissing\bold=false
data\referenceMissing\italic=false
data\referenceMissing\overline=false
data\referenceMissing\underline=false
data\referenceMissing\strikeout=false
data\referenceMissing\waveUnderline=true
data\referenceMissing\foreground=#b5d1df
data\referenceMissing\fontFamily=
data\referenceMissing\pointSize=0
data\referenceMissing\wrapAround=false
data\referenceMultiple\priority=-1
data\referenceMultiple\bold=false
data\referenceMultiple\italic=false
data\referenceMultiple\overline=false
data\referenceMultiple\underline=false
data\referenceMultiple\strikeout=false
data\referenceMultiple\waveUnderline=true
data\referenceMultiple\foreground=#40677f
data\referenceMultiple\fontFamily=
data\referenceMultiple\pointSize=0
data\referenceMultiple\wrapAround=false
data\citationPresent\priority=-1
data\citationPresent\bold=true
data\citationPresent\italic=false
data\citationPresent\overline=false
data\citationPresent\underline=false
data\citationPresent\strikeout=false
data\citationPresent\waveUnderline=false
data\citationPresent\foreground=#b5d1df
data\citationPresent\fontFamily=
data\citationPresent\pointSize=0
data\citationPresent\wrapAround=false
data\citationMissing\priority=-1
data\citationMissing\bold=true
data\citationMissing\italic=false
data\citationMissing\overline=false
data\citationMissing\underline=false
data\citationMissing\strikeout=false
data\citationMissing\waveUnderline=true
data\citationMissing\foreground=#b5d1df
data\citationMissing\fontFamily=
data\citationMissing\pointSize=0
data\citationMissing\wrapAround=false
data\packagePresent\priority=-1
data\packagePresent\bold=false
data\packagePresent\italic=false
data\packagePresent\overline=false
data\packagePresent\underline=false
data\packagePresent\strikeout=false
data\packagePresent\waveUnderline=false
data\packagePresent\foreground=#b5d1df
data\packagePresent\fontFamily=
data\packagePresent\pointSize=0
data\packagePresent\wrapAround=false
data\packageMissing\priority=-1
data\packageMissing\bold=false
data\packageMissing\italic=false
data\packageMissing\overline=false
data\packageMissing\underline=false
data\packageMissing\strikeout=false
data\packageMissing\waveUnderline=true
data\packageMissing\foreground=#b5d1df
data\packageMissing\fontFamily=
data\packageMissing\pointSize=0
data\packageMissing\wrapAround=false
data\structure\priority=-1
data\structure\bold=true
data\structure\italic=false
data\structure\overline=false
data\structure\underline=false
data\structure\strikeout=false
data\structure\waveUnderline=false
data\structure\foreground=#72aaca
data\structure\fontFamily=
data\structure\pointSize=0
data\structure\wrapAround=false
data\current\priority=-1
data\current\bold=false
data\current\italic=false
data\current\overline=false
data\current\underline=false
data\current\strikeout=false
data\current\waveUnderline=false
data\current\foreground=#ffffff
data\current\background=#4d4d4d
data\current\fontFamily=
data\current\pointSize=0
data\current\wrapAround=false
data\previewSelection\priority=-1
data\previewSelection\bold=false
data\previewSelection\italic=false
data\previewSelection\overline=false
data\previewSelection\underline=false
data\previewSelection\strikeout=false
data\previewSelection\waveUnderline=false
data\previewSelection\background=#aaffaa
data\previewSelection\fontFamily=
data\previewSelection\pointSize=0
data\previewSelection\wrapAround=true
```

The font used is **consolas**.

Comment: May I get some help with finding the TeXstudio settings file on Windows? Thanks!

Comment: @Fang Jing -> `... \AppData\Roaming\texstudio`

Comment: Thanks! Is the file called texstudio.ini in that folder?

Comment: @FangJing yes, it is

Comment: How to set this up ? I am not able to figure out anything.

Comment: @Hirak have a look at the previous comments, you have to edit the according section in the above file

Comment: Changing `texstudio.ini` works, but saving a profile, editing and then loading it does not work, I don't know why.  The profile file seems to have same format as the `texstudio.ini` file.

Comment: Have changed more than the `[formats]` section?

Answer (score 27):

[image: screensot]

A scheme based on monokai

```
[formats]
version=1.0
data\normal\priority=-1
data\normal\bold=false
data\normal\italic=false
data\normal\overline=false
data\normal\underline=false
data\normal\strikeout=false
data\normal\waveUnderline=false
data\normal\foreground=#f8f8f2
data\normal\fontFamily=
data\normal\pointSize=0
data\background\priority=-1
data\background\bold=false
data\background\italic=false
data\background\overline=false
data\background\underline=false
data\background\strikeout=false
data\background\waveUnderline=false
data\background\background=#272822
data\background\fontFamily=
data\background\pointSize=0
data\commentTodo\priority=-1
data\commentTodo\bold=false
data\commentTodo\italic=false
data\commentTodo\overline=false
data\commentTodo\underline=false
data\commentTodo\strikeout=false
data\commentTodo\waveUnderline=false
data\commentTodo\foreground=#6c71c4
data\commentTodo\fontFamily=
data\commentTodo\pointSize=0
data\comment\priority=-1
data\comment\bold=false
data\comment\italic=false
data\comment\overline=false
data\comment\underline=false
data\comment\strikeout=false
data\comment\waveUnderline=false
data\comment\foreground=#75715e
data\comment\fontFamily=
data\comment\pointSize=0
data\keyword\priority=-1
data\keyword\bold=false
data\keyword\italic=false
data\keyword\overline=false
data\keyword\underline=false
data\keyword\strikeout=false
data\keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\keyword\foreground=#f92672
data\keyword\fontFamily=
data\keyword\pointSize=0
data\extra-keyword\priority=-1
data\extra-keyword\bold=true
data\extra-keyword\italic=false
data\extra-keyword\overline=false
data\extra-keyword\underline=false
data\extra-keyword\strikeout=false
data\extra-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\extra-keyword\foreground=#f92672
data\extra-keyword\fontFamily=
data\extra-keyword\pointSize=0
data\math-keyword\priority=-1
data\math-keyword\bold=false
data\math-keyword\italic=false
data\math-keyword\overline=false
data\math-keyword\underline=false
data\math-keyword\strikeout=false
data\math-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\math-keyword\foreground=#855c1b
data\math-keyword\fontFamily=
data\math-keyword\pointSize=0
data\link\priority=-1
data\link\bold=false
data\link\italic=false
data\link\overline=false
data\link\underline=true
data\link\strikeout=false
data\link\waveUnderline=false
data\link\fontFamily=
data\link\pointSize=0
data\align-ampersand\priority=-1
data\align-ampersand\bold=true
data\align-ampersand\italic=false
data\align-ampersand\overline=false
data\align-ampersand\underline=false
data\align-ampersand\strikeout=false
data\align-ampersand\waveUnderline=false
data\align-ampersand\foreground=#77507b
data\align-ampersand\fontFamily=
data\align-ampersand\pointSize=0
data\verbatim\priority=-1
data\verbatim\bold=false
data\verbatim\italic=false
data\verbatim\overline=false
data\verbatim\underline=false
data\verbatim\strikeout=false
data\verbatim\waveUnderline=false
data\verbatim\fontFamily=
data\verbatim\pointSize=0
data\sweave\priority=-1
data\sweave\bold=false
data\sweave\italic=false
data\sweave\overline=false
data\sweave\underline=false
data\sweave\strikeout=false
data\sweave\waveUnderline=false
data\sweave\fontFamily=
data\sweave\pointSize=0
data\picture\priority=-1
data\picture\bold=false
data\picture\italic=false
data\picture\overline=false
data\picture\underline=false
data\picture\strikeout=false
data\picture\waveUnderline=false
data\picture\foreground=#f7f7f7
data\picture\fontFamily=
data\picture\pointSize=0
data\numbers\priority=-1
data\numbers\bold=false
data\numbers\italic=false
data\numbers\overline=false
data\numbers\underline=false
data\numbers\strikeout=false
data\numbers\waveUnderline=false
data\numbers\foreground=#2aa198
data\numbers\fontFamily=
data\numbers\pointSize=0
data\math-delimiter\priority=-1
data\math-delimiter\bold=true
data\math-delimiter\italic=false
data\math-delimiter\overline=false
data\math-delimiter\underline=false
data\math-delimiter\strikeout=false
data\math-delimiter\waveUnderline=false
data\math-delimiter\foreground=#77507b
data\math-delimiter\fontFamily=
data\math-delimiter\pointSize=0
data\text\priority=-1
data\text\bold=false
data\text\italic=false
data\text\overline=false
data\text\underline=false
data\text\strikeout=false
data\text\waveUnderline=false
data\text\fontFamily=
data\text\pointSize=0
data\escapeseq\priority=-1
data\escapeseq\bold=false
data\escapeseq\italic=false
data\escapeseq\overline=false
data\escapeseq\underline=false
data\escapeseq\strikeout=false
data\escapeseq\waveUnderline=false
data\escapeseq\fontFamily=
data\escapeseq\pointSize=0
data\latexSyntaxMistake\priority=-1
data\latexSyntaxMistake\bold=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\italic=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\overline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\underline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\strikeout=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\waveUnderline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\fontFamily=
data\latexSyntaxMistake\pointSize=0
data\environment\priority=-1
data\environment\bold=false
data\environment\italic=false
data\environment\overline=false
data\environment\underline=false
data\environment\strikeout=false
data\environment\waveUnderline=false
data\environment\foreground=#b58900
data\environment\fontFamily=
data\environment\pointSize=0
data\structure\priority=-1
data\structure\bold=true
data\structure\italic=false
data\structure\overline=false
data\structure\underline=false
data\structure\strikeout=false
data\structure\waveUnderline=false
data\structure\fontFamily=
data\structure\pointSize=0
data\current\priority=-1
data\current\bold=false
data\current\italic=false
data\current\overline=false
data\current\underline=false
data\current\strikeout=false
data\current\waveUnderline=false
data\current\background=#3e3d32
data\current\fontFamily=
data\current\pointSize=0
```

Comment: Could you include an image of the theme in action (like all the other answers)? See [How can I upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](http://goo.gl/59Kig)

Comment: I like this one

Answer (score 26):

I adapted the Solarized theme into Texmaker. I played around with the colors of Solarized and ended up with the following theme:

[image: Texmaker with Solarized dark theme]

You can add it at Texmaker's config file `texmaker.ini`, which should located at

- **Linux**: `$HOME/.config/xm1`
- **Windows**: `%APPDATA%/xm1`
- **Mac OS X**: `$HOME/.config/texstudio/` (In Finder, press Command+Shift+Dot to see hidden files and folders. TeXstudio cannot be running when the desired change to `texstudio.ini` is made.)

Here are the lines with the colors. They need to be replaced at the config file:

```
Color\Background=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\0\0++66\0\0)
Color\Command=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff&&\x8b\x8b\xd2\xd2\0\0)
Color\Comment=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xffllqq\xc4\xc4\0\0)
Color\Highlight=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\a\a66BB\0\0)
Color\Keyword=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\xdc\xdc\x32\x32//\0\0)
Color\KeywordGraphic=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\x85\x85\x99\x99\0\0\0\0)
Color\Line=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\a\a66BB\0\0)
Color\Math=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff**\xa1\xa1\x98\x98\0\0)
Color\NumberGraphic=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\xcb\xcbKK\x16\x16\0\0)
Color\Standard=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\x83\x83\x94\x94\x96\x96\0\0)
Color\Todo=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\xd3\xd3\x36\x36\x82\x82\0\0)
Color\Verbatim=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\xb5\xb5\x89\x89\0\0\0\0)
```

Comment: This looks great.

Comment: Can't use this theme, creating a profile and placing those lines does nothing. Tried to restart texstudio, paste into the .ini, nothing works on Win7, texstudio 2.8.4.

Comment: My posted lines are from the Texmaker config file. As far as I know, the structure of Texstudio's config file is not the same. Maybe, the [post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123133/60539) of @Lorzen can help you.

Answer (score 21):

In the same spirit, I made (what I think is the closest I could to) a clone of `Zenburn`.

[image]

```
[formats]
version=1.0
data\background\background=#3f3f3f
data\background\bold=false
data\background\fontFamily=
data\background\italic=false
data\background\overline=false
data\background\pointSize=0
data\background\priority=-1
data\background\strikeout=false
data\background\underline=false
data\background\waveUnderline=false
data\comment\bold=false
data\comment\fontFamily=
data\comment\foreground=#9fc59f
data\comment\italic=false
data\comment\overline=false
data\comment\pointSize=0
data\comment\priority=-1
data\comment\strikeout=false
data\comment\underline=false
data\comment\waveUnderline=false
data\keyword\bold=true
data\keyword\fontFamily=
data\keyword\foreground=#f0dfaf
data\keyword\italic=false
data\keyword\overline=false
data\keyword\pointSize=0
data\keyword\priority=-1
data\keyword\strikeout=false
data\keyword\underline=false
data\keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\math-keyword\bold=true
data\math-keyword\fontFamily=
data\math-keyword\foreground=#8cd0d3
data\math-keyword\italic=false
data\math-keyword\overline=false
data\math-keyword\pointSize=0
data\math-keyword\priority=-1
data\math-keyword\strikeout=false
data\math-keyword\underline=false
data\math-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\numbers\bold=false
data\numbers\fontFamily=
data\numbers\foreground=#93e0e3
data\numbers\italic=false
data\numbers\overline=false
data\numbers\pointSize=0
data\numbers\priority=-1
data\numbers\strikeout=false
data\numbers\underline=false
data\numbers\waveUnderline=false
data\align-ampersand\bold=true
data\align-ampersand\fontFamily=
data\align-ampersand\foreground=#dc8cc3
data\align-ampersand\italic=false
data\align-ampersand\overline=false
data\align-ampersand\pointSize=0
data\align-ampersand\priority=-1
data\align-ampersand\strikeout=false
data\align-ampersand\underline=false
data\align-ampersand\waveUnderline=false
data\commentTodo\bold=false
data\commentTodo\fontFamily=
data\commentTodo\foreground=#ffffef
data\commentTodo\background=#5f7f5f
data\commentTodo\italic=false
data\commentTodo\overline=false
data\commentTodo\pointSize=0
data\commentTodo\priority=-1
data\commentTodo\strikeout=false
data\commentTodo\underline=false
data\commentTodo\waveUnderline=false
data\current\background=#5f5f5f
data\current\bold=false
data\current\fontFamily=
data\current\italic=false
data\current\overline=false
data\current\pointSize=0
data\current\priority=-1
data\current\strikeout=false
data\current\underline=false
data\current\waveUnderline=false
data\environment\bold=false
data\environment\fontFamily=
data\environment\foreground=#dfaf8f
data\environment\italic=false
data\environment\overline=false
data\environment\pointSize=0
data\environment\priority=-1
data\environment\strikeout=false
data\environment\underline=false
data\environment\waveUnderline=false
data\escapeseq\bold=false
data\escapeseq\fontFamily=
data\escapeseq\italic=false
data\escapeseq\overline=false
data\escapeseq\pointSize=0
data\escapeseq\priority=-1
data\escapeseq\strikeout=false
data\escapeseq\underline=false
data\escapeseq\waveUnderline=false
data\extra-keyword\bold=true
data\extra-keyword\fontFamily=
data\extra-keyword\foreground=#d0bf8f
data\extra-keyword\italic=false
data\extra-keyword\overline=false
data\extra-keyword\pointSize=0
data\extra-keyword\priority=-1
data\extra-keyword\strikeout=false
data\extra-keyword\underline=false
data\extra-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\link\bold=false
data\link\fontFamily=
data\link\italic=false
data\link\overline=false
data\link\pointSize=0
data\link\priority=-1
data\link\strikeout=false
data\link\underline=true
data\link\waveUnderline=false
data\math-delimiter\bold=true
data\math-delimiter\fontFamily=
data\math-delimiter\foreground=#94bff3
data\math-delimiter\italic=false
data\math-delimiter\overline=false
data\math-delimiter\pointSize=0
data\math-delimiter\priority=-1
data\math-delimiter\strikeout=false
data\math-delimiter\underline=false
data\math-delimiter\waveUnderline=false
data\normal\bold=false
data\normal\fontFamily=
data\normal\foreground=#dcdccc
data\normal\italic=false
data\normal\overline=false
data\normal\pointSize=0
data\normal\priority=-1
data\normal\strikeout=false
data\normal\underline=false
data\normal\waveUnderline=false
data\picture\bold=false
data\picture\fontFamily=
data\picture\foreground=#dcdccc
data\picture\italic=false
data\picture\overline=false
data\picture\pointSize=0
data\picture\priority=-1
data\picture\strikeout=false
data\picture\underline=false
data\picture\waveUnderline=false
data\structure\bold=true
data\structure\fontFamily=
data\structure\italic=false
data\structure\overline=false
data\structure\pointSize=0
data\structure\priority=-1
data\structure\strikeout=false
data\structure\underline=false
data\structure\waveUnderline=false
data\sweave\bold=false
data\sweave\fontFamily=
data\sweave\italic=false
data\sweave\overline=false
data\sweave\pointSize=0
data\sweave\priority=-1
data\sweave\strikeout=false
data\sweave\underline=false
data\sweave\waveUnderline=false
data\text\bold=false
data\text\fontFamily=
data\text\italic=false
data\text\overline=false
data\text\pointSize=0
data\text\priority=-1
data\text\strikeout=false
data\text\underline=false
data\text\waveUnderline=false
data\verbatim\bold=false
data\verbatim\fontFamily=
data\verbatim\italic=false
data\verbatim\overline=false
data\verbatim\pointSize=0
data\verbatim\priority=-1
data\verbatim\strikeout=false
data\verbatim\underline=false
data\verbatim\waveUnderline=false
data\referencePresent\priority=-1
data\referencePresent\bold=false
data\referencePresent\italic=false
data\referencePresent\overline=false
data\referencePresent\underline=false
data\referencePresent\strikeout=false
data\referencePresent\waveUnderline=false
data\referencePresent\foreground=#dfaf8f
data\referencePresent\fontFamily=
data\referencePresent\pointSize=0
data\packagePresent\priority=-1
data\packagePresent\bold=false
data\packagePresent\italic=false
data\packagePresent\overline=false
data\packagePresent\underline=false
data\packagePresent\strikeout=false
data\packagePresent\waveUnderline=false
data\packagePresent\foreground=#dfaf8f
data\packagePresent\fontFamily=
data\packagePresent\pointSize=0
data\packageMissing\priority=-1
data\packageMissing\bold=false
data\packageMissing\italic=false
data\packageMissing\overline=false
data\packageMissing\underline=false
data\packageMissing\strikeout=false
data\packageMissing\waveUnderline=true
data\packageMissing\foreground=#dfaf8f
data\packageMissing\fontFamily=
data\packageMissing\pointSize=0
data\referenceMissing\priority=-1
data\referenceMissing\bold=false
data\referenceMissing\italic=false
data\referenceMissing\overline=false
data\referenceMissing\underline=false
data\referenceMissing\strikeout=false
data\referenceMissing\waveUnderline=true
data\referenceMissing\foreground=#dfaf8f
data\referenceMissing\fontFamily=
data\referenceMissing\pointSize=0
data\citationPresent\priority=-1
data\citationPresent\bold=false
data\citationPresent\italic=false
data\citationPresent\overline=false
data\citationPresent\underline=false
data\citationPresent\strikeout=false
data\citationPresent\waveUnderline=false
data\citationPresent\foreground=#dfaf8f
data\citationPresent\fontFamily=
data\citationPresent\pointSize=0
data\citationMissing\priority=-1
data\citationMissing\bold=false
data\citationMissing\italic=false
data\citationMissing\overline=false
data\citationMissing\underline=false
data\citationMissing\strikeout=false
data\citationMissing\waveUnderline=true
data\citationMissing\foreground=#dfaf8f
data\citationMissing\fontFamily=
data\citationMissing\pointSize=0
data\braceMatch\priority=-1
data\braceMatch\bold=true
data\braceMatch\italic=false
data\braceMatch\overline=false
data\braceMatch\underline=false
data\braceMatch\strikeout=false
data\braceMatch\waveUnderline=false
data\braceMatch\foreground=#dc8cc3
data\braceMatch\background=#2b2b2b
data\braceMatch\fontFamily=
data\braceMatch\pointSize=0
data\braceMismatch\priority=-1
data\braceMismatch\bold=true
data\braceMismatch\italic=false
data\braceMismatch\overline=false
data\braceMismatch\underline=false
data\braceMismatch\strikeout=false
data\braceMismatch\waveUnderline=false
data\braceMismatch\foreground=#2b2b2b
data\braceMismatch\background=#dc8cc3
data\braceMismatch\fontFamily=
data\braceMismatch\pointSize=0
data\spellingMistake\priority=-1
data\spellingMistake\bold=false
data\spellingMistake\italic=false
data\spellingMistake\overline=false
data\spellingMistake\underline=false
data\spellingMistake\strikeout=false
data\spellingMistake\waveUnderline=true
data\spellingMistake\linescolor=#dfaf8f
data\spellingMistake\fontFamily=
data\spellingMistake\pointSize=0
data\latexSyntaxMistake\bold=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\fontFamily=
data\latexSyntaxMistake\italic=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\linescolor=#dfaf8f
data\latexSyntaxMistake\overline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\pointSize=0
data\latexSyntaxMistake\priority=-1
data\latexSyntaxMistake\strikeout=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\underline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\waveUnderline=false
data\wordRepetition\priority=-1
data\wordRepetition\bold=false
data\wordRepetition\italic=false
data\wordRepetition\overline=false
data\wordRepetition\underline=false
data\wordRepetition\strikeout=false
data\wordRepetition\waveUnderline=true
data\wordRepetition\linescolor=#dc8cc3
data\wordRepetition\fontFamily=
data\wordRepetition\pointSize=0
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\priority=-1
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\bold=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\italic=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\overline=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\underline=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\strikeout=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\waveUnderline=true
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\linescolor=#dc8cc3
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\fontFamily=
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\pointSize=0
data\line%3Aerror\priority=-1
data\line%3Aerror\bold=false
data\line%3Aerror\italic=false
data\line%3Aerror\overline=false
data\line%3Aerror\underline=false
data\line%3Aerror\strikeout=false
data\line%3Aerror\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Aerror\background=#cc9393
data\line%3Aerror\fontFamily=
data\line%3Aerror\pointSize=0
data\structure\foreground=#ffffef
```

**Update:** I maintain now some dark themes for TeXStudio (https://gitlab.com/adin/texstudio-profiles), in case you want to get latest changes.

Comment: I love zenburn!

Comment: Cool, let me know if you find something disturbing. I just made it, and I'm tinkering with it.

Comment: Actually, I never really switched to or used texstudio. Instead, I switched from texmaker to Vim, and never looked back :)

Answer (score 16):

Here goes my config, tried to get it very similar to TexMaker

```
[formats]
version=1.0
data\normal\priority=-1
data\normal\bold=false
data\normal\italic=false
data\normal\overline=false
data\normal\underline=false
data\normal\strikeout=false
data\normal\waveUnderline=false
data\normal\foreground=#ffffff
data\normal\background=#000518
data\normal\fontFamily=Courier 10 Pitch
data\normal\pointSize=0
data\comment\priority=-1
data\comment\bold=false
data\comment\italic=false
data\comment\overline=false
data\comment\underline=false
data\comment\strikeout=false
data\comment\waveUnderline=false
data\comment\foreground=#9a9a9a
data\comment\fontFamily=
data\comment\pointSize=0
data\keyword\priority=-1
data\keyword\bold=false
data\keyword\italic=false
data\keyword\overline=false
data\keyword\underline=false
data\keyword\strikeout=false
data\keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\keyword\foreground=#4e9dec
data\keyword\fontFamily=
data\keyword\pointSize=0
data\extra-keyword\priority=-1
data\extra-keyword\bold=false
data\extra-keyword\italic=false
data\extra-keyword\overline=false
data\extra-keyword\underline=false
data\extra-keyword\strikeout=false
data\extra-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\extra-keyword\foreground=#fff700
data\extra-keyword\fontFamily=
data\extra-keyword\pointSize=0
data\math-keyword\priority=-1
data\math-keyword\bold=true
data\math-keyword\italic=false
data\math-keyword\overline=false
data\math-keyword\underline=false
data\math-keyword\strikeout=false
data\math-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\math-keyword\foreground=#488700
data\math-keyword\fontFamily=
data\math-keyword\pointSize=0
data\search\priority=-1
data\search\bold=false
data\search\italic=false
data\search\overline=false
data\search\underline=false
data\search\strikeout=false
data\search\waveUnderline=false
data\search\foreground=#55ffff
data\search\background=#ff00ff
data\search\fontFamily=
data\search\pointSize=0
data\math-delimiter\priority=-1
data\math-delimiter\bold=true
data\math-delimiter\italic=false
data\math-delimiter\overline=false
data\math-delimiter\underline=false
data\math-delimiter\strikeout=false
data\math-delimiter\waveUnderline=false
data\math-delimiter\foreground=#b90003
data\math-delimiter\fontFamily=
data\math-delimiter\pointSize=0
data\latexSyntaxMistake\priority=-1
data\latexSyntaxMistake\bold=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\italic=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\overline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\underline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\strikeout=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\waveUnderline=true
data\latexSyntaxMistake\foreground=#da0003
data\latexSyntaxMistake\fontFamily=
data\latexSyntaxMistake\pointSize=0
data\environment\priority=-1
data\environment\bold=true
data\environment\italic=false
data\environment\overline=false
data\environment\underline=false
data\environment\strikeout=false
data\environment\waveUnderline=false
data\environment\foreground=#aaaaaa
data\environment\fontFamily=
data\environment\pointSize=0
data\structure\priority=-1
data\structure\bold=true
data\structure\italic=false
data\structure\overline=false
data\structure\underline=false
data\structure\strikeout=false
data\structure\waveUnderline=false
data\structure\foreground=#cfffd3
data\structure\fontFamily=
data\structure\pointSize=0
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: Texstudio dark theme]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I added the image for you.

Comment: Thank you kind sir! The red commands are slightly jarring, and the profile gave dark text on dark background in my TS, but that was easy to fix.

Comment: I am a noob but where am i supposed to paste this?

Answer (score 13):

Some modification of the @Jubobs's answer:

```
version=1.0
data\normal\priority=-1
data\normal\bold=false
data\normal\italic=false
data\normal\overline=false
data\normal\underline=false
data\normal\strikeout=false
data\normal\waveUnderline=false
data\normal\foreground=#d6d6d6
data\normal\fontFamily=
data\normal\pointSize=0
data\background\priority=-1
data\background\bold=false
data\background\italic=false
data\background\overline=false
data\background\underline=false
data\background\strikeout=false
data\background\waveUnderline=false
data\background\background=#272822
data\background\fontFamily=
data\background\pointSize=0
data\commentTodo\priority=-1
data\commentTodo\bold=false
data\commentTodo\italic=false
data\commentTodo\overline=false
data\commentTodo\underline=false
data\commentTodo\strikeout=false
data\commentTodo\waveUnderline=false
data\commentTodo\foreground=#6c71c4
data\commentTodo\fontFamily=
data\commentTodo\pointSize=0
data\comment\priority=-1
data\comment\bold=false
data\comment\italic=false
data\comment\overline=false
data\comment\underline=false
data\comment\strikeout=false
data\comment\waveUnderline=false
data\comment\foreground=#586e75
data\comment\fontFamily=
data\comment\pointSize=0
data\keyword\priority=-1
data\keyword\bold=false
data\keyword\italic=false
data\keyword\overline=false
data\keyword\underline=false
data\keyword\strikeout=false
data\keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\keyword\foreground=#cb4b16
data\keyword\fontFamily=
data\keyword\pointSize=0
data\extra-keyword\priority=-1
data\extra-keyword\bold=true
data\extra-keyword\italic=false
data\extra-keyword\overline=false
data\extra-keyword\underline=false
data\extra-keyword\strikeout=false
data\extra-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\extra-keyword\foreground=#859900
data\extra-keyword\fontFamily=
data\extra-keyword\pointSize=0
data\math-keyword\priority=-1
data\math-keyword\bold=false
data\math-keyword\italic=false
data\math-keyword\overline=false
data\math-keyword\underline=false
data\math-keyword\strikeout=false
data\math-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\math-keyword\foreground=#268bd2
data\math-keyword\fontFamily=
data\math-keyword\pointSize=0
data\link\priority=-1
data\link\bold=false
data\link\italic=false
data\link\overline=false
data\link\underline=true
data\link\strikeout=false
data\link\waveUnderline=false
data\link\fontFamily=
data\link\pointSize=0
data\align-ampersand\priority=-1
data\align-ampersand\bold=true
data\align-ampersand\italic=false
data\align-ampersand\overline=false
data\align-ampersand\underline=false
data\align-ampersand\strikeout=false
data\align-ampersand\waveUnderline=false
data\align-ampersand\foreground=#dc322f
data\align-ampersand\fontFamily=
data\align-ampersand\pointSize=0
data\verbatim\priority=-1
data\verbatim\bold=false
data\verbatim\italic=false
data\verbatim\overline=false
data\verbatim\underline=false
data\verbatim\strikeout=false
data\verbatim\waveUnderline=false
data\verbatim\fontFamily=
data\verbatim\pointSize=0
data\sweave\priority=0
data\sweave\bold=false
data\sweave\italic=false
data\sweave\overline=false
data\sweave\underline=false
data\sweave\strikeout=false
data\sweave\waveUnderline=false
data\sweave\fontFamily=
data\sweave\pointSize=0
data\picture\priority=-1
data\picture\bold=false
data\picture\italic=false
data\picture\overline=false
data\picture\underline=false
data\picture\strikeout=false
data\picture\waveUnderline=false
data\picture\foreground=#c93682
data\picture\fontFamily=
data\picture\pointSize=0
data\numbers\priority=-1
data\numbers\bold=false
data\numbers\italic=false
data\numbers\overline=false
data\numbers\underline=false
data\numbers\strikeout=false
data\numbers\waveUnderline=false
data\numbers\foreground=#2aa198
data\numbers\fontFamily=
data\numbers\pointSize=0
data\math-delimiter\priority=-1
data\math-delimiter\bold=true
data\math-delimiter\italic=false
data\math-delimiter\overline=false
data\math-delimiter\underline=false
data\math-delimiter\strikeout=false
data\math-delimiter\waveUnderline=false
data\math-delimiter\foreground=#399900
data\math-delimiter\fontFamily=
data\math-delimiter\pointSize=0
data\text\priority=-1
data\text\bold=false
data\text\italic=false
data\text\overline=false
data\text\underline=false
data\text\strikeout=false
data\text\waveUnderline=false
data\text\fontFamily=
data\text\pointSize=0
data\escapeseq\priority=-1
data\escapeseq\bold=false
data\escapeseq\italic=false
data\escapeseq\overline=false
data\escapeseq\underline=false
data\escapeseq\strikeout=false
data\escapeseq\waveUnderline=false
data\escapeseq\fontFamily=
data\escapeseq\pointSize=0
data\latexSyntaxMistake\priority=-1
data\latexSyntaxMistake\bold=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\italic=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\overline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\underline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\strikeout=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\waveUnderline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\fontFamily=
data\latexSyntaxMistake\pointSize=0
data\environment\priority=-1
data\environment\bold=false
data\environment\italic=false
data\environment\overline=false
data\environment\underline=false
data\environment\strikeout=false
data\environment\waveUnderline=true
data\environment\foreground=#b58900
data\environment\fontFamily=
data\environment\pointSize=0
data\structure\priority=-1
data\structure\bold=true
data\structure\italic=false
data\structure\overline=false
data\structure\underline=false
data\structure\strikeout=false
data\structure\waveUnderline=false
data\structure\fontFamily=
data\structure\foreground=#fffffa
data\structure\pointSize=0
data\current\priority=-1
data\current\bold=false
data\current\italic=false
data\current\overline=false
data\current\underline=false
data\current\strikeout=false
data\current\waveUnderline=false
data\current\background=#5e6416
data\current\fontFamily=
data\current\pointSize=2
data\current\foreground=#5e6416
```

The result is...[image]
Tex file was taken from [here](http://www.math.duke.edu/computing/tex/templates/1percent.tex)

Answer (score 9):

I also tried a bit around. Resulting in something like:

[image]

Using Windows I first downloded a DIN-like font package e.g. [here](http://font.ubuntu.com/).

The values under [format] in the **.txsprofile* are the following:

```
version=1.0 
data\normal\priority=-1
data\normal\bold=false
data\normal\italic=false
data\normal\overline=false
data\normal\underline=false
data\normal\strikeout=false
data\normal\waveUnderline=false
data\normal\foreground=#839496
data\normal\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\normal\pointSize=0
data\background\priority=-1
data\background\bold=false
data\background\italic=false
data\background\overline=false
data\background\underline=false
data\background\strikeout=false
data\background\waveUnderline=false
data\background\background=#002b36
data\background\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\background\pointSize=0
data\line%3Aerror\priority=-1
data\line%3Aerror\bold=false
data\line%3Aerror\italic=false
data\line%3Aerror\overline=false
data\line%3Aerror\underline=false
data\line%3Aerror\strikeout=false
data\line%3Aerror\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Aerror\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\line%3Aerror\pointSize=0
data\line%3Awarning\priority=-1
data\line%3Awarning\bold=false
data\line%3Awarning\italic=false
data\line%3Awarning\overline=false
data\line%3Awarning\underline=false
data\line%3Awarning\strikeout=false
data\line%3Awarning\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Awarning\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\line%3Awarning\pointSize=0
data\line%3Abadbox\priority=-1
data\line%3Abadbox\bold=false
data\line%3Abadbox\italic=false
data\line%3Abadbox\overline=false
data\line%3Abadbox\underline=false
data\line%3Abadbox\strikeout=false
data\line%3Abadbox\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Abadbox\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\line%3Abadbox\pointSize=0
data\line%3Abookmark\priority=-1
data\line%3Abookmark\bold=false
data\line%3Abookmark\italic=false
data\line%3Abookmark\overline=false
data\line%3Abookmark\underline=false
data\line%3Abookmark\strikeout=false
data\line%3Abookmark\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Abookmark\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\line%3Abookmark\pointSize=0
data\line%3Abookmark0\priority=-1
data\line%3Abookmark0\bold=false
data\line%3Abookmark0\italic=false
data\line%3Abookmark0\overline=false
data\line%3Abookmark0\underline=false
data\line%3Abookmark0\strikeout=false
data\line%3Abookmark0\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Abookmark0\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\line%3Abookmark0\pointSize=0
data\line%3Abookmark1\priority=-1
data\line%3Abookmark1\bold=false
data\line%3Abookmark1\italic=false
data\line%3Abookmark1\overline=false
data\line%3Abookmark1\underline=false
data\line%3Abookmark1\strikeout=false
data\line%3Abookmark1\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Abookmark1\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\line%3Abookmark1\pointSize=0
data\line%3Abookmark2\priority=-1
data\line%3Abookmark2\bold=false
data\line%3Abookmark2\italic=false
data\line%3Abookmark2\overline=false
data\line%3Abookmark2\underline=false
data\line%3Abookmark2\strikeout=false
data\line%3Abookmark2\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Abookmark2\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\line%3Abookmark2\pointSize=0
data\line%3Abookmark3\priority=-1
data\line%3Abookmark3\bold=false
data\line%3Abookmark3\italic=false
data\line%3Abookmark3\overline=false
data\line%3Abookmark3\underline=false
data\line%3Abookmark3\strikeout=false
data\line%3Abookmark3\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Abookmark3\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\line%3Abookmark3\pointSize=0
data\line%3Abookmark4\priority=-1
data\line%3Abookmark4\bold=false
data\line%3Abookmark4\italic=false
data\line%3Abookmark4\overline=false
data\line%3Abookmark4\underline=false
data\line%3Abookmark4\strikeout=false
data\line%3Abookmark4\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Abookmark4\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\line%3Abookmark4\pointSize=0
data\line%3Abookmark5\priority=-1
data\line%3Abookmark5\bold=false
data\line%3Abookmark5\italic=false
data\line%3Abookmark5\overline=false
data\line%3Abookmark5\underline=false
data\line%3Abookmark5\strikeout=false
data\line%3Abookmark5\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Abookmark5\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\line%3Abookmark5\pointSize=0
data\line%3Abookmark6\priority=-1
data\line%3Abookmark6\bold=false
data\line%3Abookmark6\italic=false
data\line%3Abookmark6\overline=false
data\line%3Abookmark6\underline=false
data\line%3Abookmark6\strikeout=false
data\line%3Abookmark6\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Abookmark6\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\line%3Abookmark6\pointSize=0
data\line%3Abookmark7\priority=-1
data\line%3Abookmark7\bold=false
data\line%3Abookmark7\italic=false
data\line%3Abookmark7\overline=false
data\line%3Abookmark7\underline=false
data\line%3Abookmark7\strikeout=false
data\line%3Abookmark7\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Abookmark7\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\line%3Abookmark7\pointSize=0
data\line%3Abookmark8\priority=-1
data\line%3Abookmark8\bold=false
data\line%3Abookmark8\italic=false
data\line%3Abookmark8\overline=false
data\line%3Abookmark8\underline=false
data\line%3Abookmark8\strikeout=false
data\line%3Abookmark8\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Abookmark8\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\line%3Abookmark8\pointSize=0
data\line%3Abookmark9\priority=-1
data\line%3Abookmark9\bold=false
data\line%3Abookmark9\italic=false
data\line%3Abookmark9\overline=false
data\line%3Abookmark9\underline=false
data\line%3Abookmark9\strikeout=false
data\line%3Abookmark9\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Abookmark9\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\line%3Abookmark9\pointSize=0
data\commentTodo\priority=-1
data\commentTodo\bold=false
data\commentTodo\italic=false
data\commentTodo\overline=false
data\commentTodo\underline=false
data\commentTodo\strikeout=false
data\commentTodo\waveUnderline=false
data\commentTodo\foreground=#6c71c4
data\commentTodo\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\commentTodo\pointSize=0
data\comment\priority=-1
data\comment\bold=false
data\comment\italic=false
data\comment\overline=false
data\comment\underline=false
data\comment\strikeout=false
data\comment\waveUnderline=false
data\comment\foreground=#586e75
data\comment\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\comment\pointSize=0
data\keyword\priority=-1
data\keyword\bold=false
data\keyword\italic=false
data\keyword\overline=false
data\keyword\underline=false
data\keyword\strikeout=false
data\keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\keyword\foreground=#268bd2
data\keyword\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\keyword\pointSize=0
data\extra-keyword\priority=-1
data\extra-keyword\bold=true
data\extra-keyword\italic=false
data\extra-keyword\overline=false
data\extra-keyword\underline=false
data\extra-keyword\strikeout=false
data\extra-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\extra-keyword\foreground=#859900
data\extra-keyword\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\extra-keyword\pointSize=0
data\math-keyword\priority=-1
data\math-keyword\bold=false
data\math-keyword\italic=false
data\math-keyword\overline=false
data\math-keyword\underline=false
data\math-keyword\strikeout=false
data\math-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\math-keyword\foreground=#2aa198
data\math-keyword\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\math-keyword\pointSize=0
data\link\priority=-1
data\link\bold=false
data\link\italic=false
data\link\overline=false
data\link\underline=true
data\link\strikeout=false
data\link\waveUnderline=false
data\link\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\link\pointSize=0
data\align-ampersand\priority=-1
data\align-ampersand\bold=true
data\align-ampersand\italic=false
data\align-ampersand\overline=false
data\align-ampersand\underline=false
data\align-ampersand\strikeout=false
data\align-ampersand\waveUnderline=false
data\align-ampersand\foreground=#dc322f
data\align-ampersand\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\align-ampersand\pointSize=0
data\verbatim\priority=-1
data\verbatim\bold=false
data\verbatim\italic=false
data\verbatim\overline=false
data\verbatim\underline=false
data\verbatim\strikeout=false
data\verbatim\waveUnderline=false
data\verbatim\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\verbatim\pointSize=0
data\sweave-block\priority=-1
data\sweave-block\bold=false
data\sweave-block\italic=false
data\sweave-block\overline=false
data\sweave-block\underline=false
data\sweave-block\strikeout=false
data\sweave-block\waveUnderline=false
data\sweave-block\foreground=#800000
data\sweave-block\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\sweave-block\pointSize=0
data\sweave-delimiter\priority=-1
data\sweave-delimiter\bold=true
data\sweave-delimiter\italic=false
data\sweave-delimiter\overline=false
data\sweave-delimiter\underline=false
data\sweave-delimiter\strikeout=false
data\sweave-delimiter\waveUnderline=false
data\sweave-delimiter\foreground=#0095ff
data\sweave-delimiter\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\sweave-delimiter\pointSize=0
data\pweave-block\priority=-1
data\pweave-block\bold=false
data\pweave-block\italic=false
data\pweave-block\overline=false
data\pweave-block\underline=false
data\pweave-block\strikeout=false
data\pweave-block\waveUnderline=false
data\pweave-block\foreground=#800000
data\pweave-block\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\pweave-block\pointSize=0
data\pweave-delimiter\priority=-1
data\pweave-delimiter\bold=true
data\pweave-delimiter\italic=false
data\pweave-delimiter\overline=false
data\pweave-delimiter\underline=false
data\pweave-delimiter\strikeout=false
data\pweave-delimiter\waveUnderline=false
data\pweave-delimiter\foreground=#0095ff
data\pweave-delimiter\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\pweave-delimiter\pointSize=0
data\picture\priority=-1
data\picture\bold=false
data\picture\italic=false
data\picture\overline=false
data\picture\underline=false
data\picture\strikeout=false
data\picture\waveUnderline=false
data\picture\foreground=#c93682
data\picture\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\picture\pointSize=0
data\braceMatch\priority=-1
data\braceMatch\bold=true
data\braceMatch\italic=false
data\braceMatch\overline=false
data\braceMatch\underline=false
data\braceMatch\strikeout=false
data\braceMatch\waveUnderline=false
data\braceMatch\foreground=#c00000
data\braceMatch\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\braceMatch\pointSize=0
data\braceMismatch\priority=-1
data\braceMismatch\bold=true
data\braceMismatch\italic=false
data\braceMismatch\overline=false
data\braceMismatch\underline=false
data\braceMismatch\strikeout=false
data\braceMismatch\waveUnderline=false
data\braceMismatch\foreground=#ffff7f
data\braceMismatch\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\braceMismatch\pointSize=0
data\search\priority=-1
data\search\bold=false
data\search\italic=false
data\search\overline=false
data\search\underline=false
data\search\strikeout=false
data\search\waveUnderline=false
data\search\foreground=#000000
data\search\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\search\pointSize=0
data\numbers\priority=-1
data\numbers\bold=false
data\numbers\italic=false
data\numbers\overline=false
data\numbers\underline=false
data\numbers\strikeout=false
data\numbers\waveUnderline=false
data\numbers\foreground=#b58900
data\numbers\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\numbers\pointSize=0
data\math-delimiter\priority=-1
data\math-delimiter\bold=true
data\math-delimiter\italic=false
data\math-delimiter\overline=false
data\math-delimiter\underline=false
data\math-delimiter\strikeout=false
data\math-delimiter\waveUnderline=false
data\math-delimiter\foreground=#399900
data\math-delimiter\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\math-delimiter\pointSize=0
data\text\priority=-1
data\text\bold=false
data\text\italic=false
data\text\overline=false
data\text\underline=false
data\text\strikeout=false
data\text\waveUnderline=false
data\text\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\text\pointSize=0
data\escapeseq\priority=-1
data\escapeseq\bold=false
data\escapeseq\italic=false
data\escapeseq\overline=false
data\escapeseq\underline=false
data\escapeseq\strikeout=false
data\escapeseq\waveUnderline=false
data\escapeseq\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\escapeseq\pointSize=0
data\spellingMistake\priority=-1
data\spellingMistake\bold=false
data\spellingMistake\italic=false
data\spellingMistake\overline=false
data\spellingMistake\underline=false
data\spellingMistake\strikeout=false
data\spellingMistake\waveUnderline=true
data\spellingMistake\linescolor=#ff0000
data\spellingMistake\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\spellingMistake\pointSize=0
data\wordRepetition\priority=-1
data\wordRepetition\bold=false
data\wordRepetition\italic=false
data\wordRepetition\overline=false
data\wordRepetition\underline=false
data\wordRepetition\strikeout=false
data\wordRepetition\waveUnderline=true
data\wordRepetition\linescolor=#008000
data\wordRepetition\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\wordRepetition\pointSize=0
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\priority=-1
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\bold=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\italic=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\overline=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\underline=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\strikeout=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\waveUnderline=true
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\linescolor=#008000
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\pointSize=0
data\badWord\priority=-1
data\badWord\bold=false
data\badWord\italic=false
data\badWord\overline=false
data\badWord\underline=false
data\badWord\strikeout=true
data\badWord\waveUnderline=false
data\badWord\linescolor=#d600a4
data\badWord\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\badWord\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistake\priority=-1
data\grammarMistake\bold=false
data\grammarMistake\italic=false
data\grammarMistake\overline=false
data\grammarMistake\underline=false
data\grammarMistake\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistake\waveUnderline=true
data\grammarMistake\linescolor=#000080
data\grammarMistake\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\grammarMistake\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\priority=-1
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\bold=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\italic=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\overline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\underline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\waveUnderline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\priority=-1
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\bold=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\italic=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\overline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\underline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\waveUnderline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\priority=-1
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\bold=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\italic=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\overline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\underline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\waveUnderline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\priority=-1
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\bold=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\italic=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\overline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\underline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\waveUnderline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\pointSize=0
data\latexSyntaxMistake\priority=-1
data\latexSyntaxMistake\bold=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\italic=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\overline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\underline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\strikeout=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\waveUnderline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\linescolor=#d90003
data\latexSyntaxMistake\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\latexSyntaxMistake\pointSize=0
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\priority=-1
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\bold=false
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\italic=true
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\overline=false
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\underline=false
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\strikeout=false
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\waveUnderline=false
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\foreground=#0000ff
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\temporaryCodeCompletion\pointSize=0
data\environment\priority=-1
data\environment\bold=false
data\environment\italic=false
data\environment\overline=false
data\environment\underline=false
data\environment\strikeout=false
data\environment\waveUnderline=false
data\environment\foreground=#b58900
data\environment\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\environment\pointSize=0
data\referencePresent\priority=-1
data\referencePresent\bold=false
data\referencePresent\italic=false
data\referencePresent\overline=false
data\referencePresent\underline=false
data\referencePresent\strikeout=false
data\referencePresent\waveUnderline=false
data\referencePresent\foreground=#008000
data\referencePresent\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\referencePresent\pointSize=0
data\referenceMissing\priority=-1
data\referenceMissing\bold=false
data\referenceMissing\italic=false
data\referenceMissing\overline=false
data\referenceMissing\underline=false
data\referenceMissing\strikeout=false
data\referenceMissing\waveUnderline=true
data\referenceMissing\foreground=#008000
data\referenceMissing\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\referenceMissing\pointSize=0
data\referenceMultiple\priority=-1
data\referenceMultiple\bold=false
data\referenceMultiple\italic=false
data\referenceMultiple\overline=false
data\referenceMultiple\underline=false
data\referenceMultiple\strikeout=false
data\referenceMultiple\waveUnderline=true
data\referenceMultiple\foreground=#800080
data\referenceMultiple\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\referenceMultiple\pointSize=0
data\citationPresent\priority=-1
data\citationPresent\bold=false
data\citationPresent\italic=false
data\citationPresent\overline=false
data\citationPresent\underline=false
data\citationPresent\strikeout=false
data\citationPresent\waveUnderline=false
data\citationPresent\foreground=#008000
data\citationPresent\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\citationPresent\pointSize=0
data\citationMissing\priority=-1
data\citationMissing\bold=false
data\citationMissing\italic=false
data\citationMissing\overline=false
data\citationMissing\underline=false
data\citationMissing\strikeout=false
data\citationMissing\waveUnderline=true
data\citationMissing\foreground=#008000
data\citationMissing\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\citationMissing\pointSize=0
data\structure\priority=-1
data\structure\bold=true
data\structure\italic=false
data\structure\overline=false
data\structure\underline=false
data\structure\strikeout=false
data\structure\waveUnderline=false
data\structure\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\structure\pointSize=0
data\current\priority=-1
data\current\bold=false
data\current\italic=false
data\current\overline=false
data\current\underline=false
data\current\strikeout=false
data\current\waveUnderline=false
data\current\background=#073642
data\current\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\current\pointSize=0
data\selection\priority=-1
data\selection\bold=false
data\selection\italic=false
data\selection\overline=false
data\selection\underline=false
data\selection\strikeout=false
data\selection\waveUnderline=false
data\selection\background=#aaffff
data\selection\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\selection\pointSize=0
data\replacement\priority=-1
data\replacement\bold=false
data\replacement\italic=false
data\replacement\overline=false
data\replacement\underline=false
data\replacement\strikeout=false
data\replacement\waveUnderline=false
data\replacement\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\replacement\pointSize=0
data\diffDelete\priority=-1
data\diffDelete\bold=false
data\diffDelete\italic=false
data\diffDelete\overline=false
data\diffDelete\underline=false
data\diffDelete\strikeout=true
data\diffDelete\waveUnderline=false
data\diffDelete\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\diffDelete\pointSize=0
data\diffAdd\priority=-1
data\diffAdd\bold=false
data\diffAdd\italic=false
data\diffAdd\overline=false
data\diffAdd\underline=false
data\diffAdd\strikeout=false
data\diffAdd\waveUnderline=false
data\diffAdd\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\diffAdd\pointSize=0
data\diffReplace\priority=-1
data\diffReplace\bold=false
data\diffReplace\italic=false
data\diffReplace\overline=false
data\diffReplace\underline=false
data\diffReplace\strikeout=false
data\diffReplace\waveUnderline=false
data\diffReplace\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\diffReplace\pointSize=0
data\dtx%3Aguard\priority=-1
data\dtx%3Aguard\bold=false
data\dtx%3Aguard\italic=false
data\dtx%3Aguard\overline=false
data\dtx%3Aguard\underline=false
data\dtx%3Aguard\strikeout=false
data\dtx%3Aguard\waveUnderline=false
data\dtx%3Aguard\foreground=#ffa500
data\dtx%3Aguard\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\dtx%3Aguard\pointSize=0
data\dtx%3Amacro\priority=-1
data\dtx%3Amacro\bold=true
data\dtx%3Amacro\italic=false
data\dtx%3Amacro\overline=false
data\dtx%3Amacro\underline=false
data\dtx%3Amacro\strikeout=false
data\dtx%3Amacro\waveUnderline=false
data\dtx%3Amacro\foreground=#006400
data\dtx%3Amacro\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\dtx%3Amacro\pointSize=0
data\dtx%3Averbatim\priority=-1
data\dtx%3Averbatim\bold=false
data\dtx%3Averbatim\italic=false
data\dtx%3Averbatim\overline=false
data\dtx%3Averbatim\underline=false
data\dtx%3Averbatim\strikeout=false
data\dtx%3Averbatim\waveUnderline=false
data\dtx%3Averbatim\foreground=#008080
data\dtx%3Averbatim\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\dtx%3Averbatim\pointSize=0
data\dtx%3Aspecialchar\priority=-1
data\dtx%3Aspecialchar\bold=false
data\dtx%3Aspecialchar\italic=false
data\dtx%3Aspecialchar\overline=false
data\dtx%3Aspecialchar\underline=false
data\dtx%3Aspecialchar\strikeout=false
data\dtx%3Aspecialchar\waveUnderline=false
data\dtx%3Aspecialchar\foreground=#cc8100
data\dtx%3Aspecialchar\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\dtx%3Aspecialchar\pointSize=0
data\lua%3Akeyword\priority=-1
data\lua%3Akeyword\bold=false
data\lua%3Akeyword\italic=false
data\lua%3Akeyword\overline=false
data\lua%3Akeyword\underline=false
data\lua%3Akeyword\strikeout=false
data\lua%3Akeyword\waveUnderline=false
data\lua%3Akeyword\foreground=#b200ff
data\lua%3Akeyword\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\lua%3Akeyword\pointSize=0
data\lua%3Acomment\priority=-1
data\lua%3Acomment\bold=false
data\lua%3Acomment\italic=false
data\lua%3Acomment\overline=false
data\lua%3Acomment\underline=false
data\lua%3Acomment\strikeout=false
data\lua%3Acomment\waveUnderline=false
data\lua%3Acomment\foreground=#808080
data\lua%3Acomment\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\lua%3Acomment\pointSize=0
data\preedit\priority=-1
data\preedit\bold=false
data\preedit\italic=false
data\preedit\overline=false
data\preedit\underline=false
data\preedit\strikeout=false
data\preedit\waveUnderline=false
data\preedit\fontFamily=Ubuntu
data\preedit\pointSize=0
```

Comment: How can I get a darker background?

Comment: This line does it: data\background\background=#002b36
you might try #001419 instead. its a darker (hex) color.

Answer (score 8):

Matrix style color theme.

The screen capture shows what the text will look like under `tikz` env, regular text, keywords like `newcommand`, and mathmode.

```
[formats]
version=1.0
data\normal\priority=-1
data\normal\bold=false
data\normal\italic=false
data\normal\overline=false
data\normal\underline=false
data\normal\strikeout=false
data\normal\waveUnderline=false
data\normal\foreground=#1fd64d
data\normal\fontFamily=
data\normal\pointSize=0
data\background\priority=-1
data\background\bold=false
data\background\italic=false
data\background\overline=false
data\background\underline=false
data\background\strikeout=false
data\background\waveUnderline=false
data\background\background=#000000
data\background\fontFamily=
data\background\pointSize=0
data\commentTodo\priority=-1
data\commentTodo\bold=false
data\commentTodo\italic=false
data\commentTodo\overline=false
data\commentTodo\underline=false
data\commentTodo\strikeout=false
data\commentTodo\waveUnderline=false
data\commentTodo\foreground=#6c71c4
data\commentTodo\fontFamily=
data\commentTodo\pointSize=0
data\comment\priority=-1
data\comment\bold=false
data\comment\italic=false
data\comment\overline=false
data\comment\underline=false
data\comment\strikeout=false
data\comment\waveUnderline=false
data\comment\foreground=#586e75
data\comment\fontFamily=
data\comment\pointSize=0
data\keyword\priority=-1
data\keyword\bold=false
data\keyword\italic=false
data\keyword\overline=false
data\keyword\underline=false
data\keyword\strikeout=false
data\keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\keyword\foreground=#149191
data\keyword\fontFamily=
data\keyword\pointSize=0
data\extra-keyword\priority=-1
data\extra-keyword\bold=true
data\extra-keyword\italic=false
data\extra-keyword\overline=false
data\extra-keyword\underline=false
data\extra-keyword\strikeout=false
data\extra-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\extra-keyword\foreground=#47c2c0
data\extra-keyword\fontFamily=
data\extra-keyword\pointSize=0
data\math-keyword\priority=-1
data\math-keyword\bold=false
data\math-keyword\italic=false
data\math-keyword\overline=false
data\math-keyword\underline=false
data\math-keyword\strikeout=false
data\math-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\math-keyword\foreground=#268bd2
data\math-keyword\fontFamily=
data\math-keyword\pointSize=0
data\verbatim\priority=-1
data\verbatim\bold=false
data\verbatim\italic=false
data\verbatim\overline=false
data\verbatim\underline=false
data\verbatim\strikeout=false
data\verbatim\waveUnderline=false
data\verbatim\fontFamily=
data\verbatim\pointSize=0
data\sweave\priority=0
data\sweave\bold=false
data\sweave\italic=false
data\sweave\overline=false
data\sweave\underline=false
data\sweave\strikeout=false
data\sweave\waveUnderline=false
data\sweave\fontFamily=
data\sweave\pointSize=0
data\picture\priority=-1
data\picture\bold=false
data\picture\italic=false
data\picture\overline=false
data\picture\underline=false
data\picture\strikeout=false
data\picture\waveUnderline=false
data\picture\foreground=#c93682
data\picture\fontFamily=
data\picture\pointSize=0
data\braceMatch\priority=-1
data\braceMatch\bold=true
data\braceMatch\italic=false
data\braceMatch\overline=false
data\braceMatch\underline=false
data\braceMatch\strikeout=false
data\braceMatch\waveUnderline=false
data\braceMatch\foreground=#b60000
data\braceMatch\background=#8a8a00
data\braceMatch\fontFamily=
data\braceMatch\pointSize=0
data\braceMismatch\priority=-1
data\braceMismatch\bold=true
data\braceMismatch\italic=false
data\braceMismatch\overline=false
data\braceMismatch\underline=false
data\braceMismatch\strikeout=false
data\braceMismatch\waveUnderline=false
data\braceMismatch\foreground=#ecec00
data\braceMismatch\background=#ff0000
data\braceMismatch\fontFamily=
data\braceMismatch\pointSize=0
data\numbers\priority=-1
data\numbers\bold=false
data\numbers\italic=false
data\numbers\overline=false
data\numbers\underline=false
data\numbers\strikeout=false
data\numbers\waveUnderline=false
data\numbers\foreground=#2aa198
data\numbers\fontFamily=
data\numbers\pointSize=0
data\text\priority=-1
data\text\bold=false
data\text\italic=false
data\text\overline=false
data\text\underline=false
data\text\strikeout=false
data\text\waveUnderline=false
data\text\fontFamily=
data\text\pointSize=0
data\escapeseq\priority=-1
data\escapeseq\bold=false
data\escapeseq\italic=false
data\escapeseq\overline=false
data\escapeseq\underline=false
data\escapeseq\strikeout=false
data\escapeseq\waveUnderline=false
data\escapeseq\fontFamily=
data\escapeseq\pointSize=0
data\spellingMistake\priority=-1
data\spellingMistake\bold=false
data\spellingMistake\italic=false
data\spellingMistake\overline=false
data\spellingMistake\underline=false
data\spellingMistake\strikeout=false
data\spellingMistake\waveUnderline=true
data\spellingMistake\linescolor=#d52a1e
data\spellingMistake\fontFamily=
data\spellingMistake\pointSize=0
data\latexSyntaxMistake\priority=-1
data\latexSyntaxMistake\bold=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\italic=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\overline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\underline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\strikeout=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\waveUnderline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\fontFamily=
data\latexSyntaxMistake\pointSize=0
data\environment\priority=-1
data\environment\bold=false
data\environment\italic=false
data\environment\overline=false
data\environment\underline=true
data\environment\strikeout=false
data\environment\waveUnderline=false
data\environment\foreground=#b58900
data\environment\fontFamily=
data\environment\pointSize=0
data\structure\priority=-1
data\structure\bold=true
data\structure\italic=false
data\structure\overline=false
data\structure\underline=false
data\structure\strikeout=false
data\structure\waveUnderline=false
data\structure\foreground=#13d6ff
data\structure\fontFamily=
data\structure\pointSize=0
data\current\priority=-1
data\current\bold=false
data\current\italic=false
data\current\overline=false
data\current\underline=false
data\current\strikeout=false
data\current\waveUnderline=false
data\current\foreground=#2e310b
data\current\background=#272a09
data\current\fontFamily=
data\current\pointSize=2
data\selection\priority=-1
data\selection\bold=false
data\selection\italic=false
data\selection\overline=false
data\selection\underline=false
data\selection\strikeout=false
data\selection\waveUnderline=false
data\selection\background=#93dcdc
data\selection\fontFamily=
data\selection\pointSize=0
data\replacement\priority=-1
data\replacement\bold=false
data\replacement\italic=false
data\replacement\overline=false
data\replacement\underline=false
data\replacement\strikeout=false
data\replacement\waveUnderline=false
data\replacement\background=#ffdede
data\replacement\fontFamily=
data\replacement\pointSize=0
```

[image: matrix]

[image: matrix2]

Answer (score 8):

### **Desert Theme**

Well, it is not that dark but not white also.

[image]

```
[formats]
version=1.0
data\normal\priority=-1
data\normal\bold=false
data\normal\italic=false
data\normal\overline=false
data\normal\underline=false
data\normal\strikeout=false
data\normal\waveUnderline=false
data\normal\foreground=#000000
data\normal\fontFamily=
data\normal\pointSize=0
data\background\priority=-1
data\background\bold=false
data\background\italic=false
data\background\overline=false
data\background\underline=false
data\background\strikeout=false
data\background\waveUnderline=false
data\background\background=#aaaa7f
data\background\fontFamily=
data\background\pointSize=0
data\line%3Aerror\priority=-1
data\line%3Aerror\bold=false
data\line%3Aerror\italic=false
data\line%3Aerror\overline=false
data\line%3Aerror\underline=false
data\line%3Aerror\strikeout=false
data\line%3Aerror\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Aerror\fontFamily=
data\line%3Aerror\pointSize=0
data\line%3Awarning\priority=-1
data\line%3Awarning\bold=false
data\line%3Awarning\italic=false
data\line%3Awarning\overline=false
data\line%3Awarning\underline=false
data\line%3Awarning\strikeout=false
data\line%3Awarning\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Awarning\fontFamily=
data\line%3Awarning\pointSize=0
data\line%3Abadbox\priority=-1
data\line%3Abadbox\bold=false
data\line%3Abadbox\italic=false
data\line%3Abadbox\overline=false
data\line%3Abadbox\underline=false
data\line%3Abadbox\strikeout=false
data\line%3Abadbox\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Abadbox\fontFamily=
data\line%3Abadbox\pointSize=0
data\commentTodo\priority=-1
data\commentTodo\bold=false
data\commentTodo\italic=false
data\commentTodo\overline=false
data\commentTodo\underline=false
data\commentTodo\strikeout=false
data\commentTodo\waveUnderline=false
data\commentTodo\foreground=#ffff7f
data\commentTodo\fontFamily=
data\commentTodo\pointSize=0
data\comment\priority=-1
data\comment\bold=false
data\comment\italic=false
data\comment\overline=false
data\comment\underline=false
data\comment\strikeout=false
data\comment\waveUnderline=false
data\comment\foreground=#64634a
data\comment\fontFamily=
data\comment\pointSize=0
data\keyword\priority=-1
data\keyword\bold=false
data\keyword\italic=false
data\keyword\overline=false
data\keyword\underline=false
data\keyword\strikeout=false
data\keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\keyword\foreground=#ffaaff
data\keyword\fontFamily=
data\keyword\pointSize=0
data\extra-keyword\priority=-1
data\extra-keyword\bold=true
data\extra-keyword\italic=false
data\extra-keyword\overline=false
data\extra-keyword\underline=false
data\extra-keyword\strikeout=false
data\extra-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\extra-keyword\foreground=#783c00
data\extra-keyword\fontFamily=
data\extra-keyword\pointSize=0
data\math-keyword\priority=-1
data\math-keyword\bold=false
data\math-keyword\italic=false
data\math-keyword\overline=false
data\math-keyword\underline=false
data\math-keyword\strikeout=false
data\math-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\math-keyword\foreground=#00ffff
data\math-keyword\fontFamily=
data\math-keyword\pointSize=0
data\link\priority=-1
data\link\bold=false
data\link\italic=false
data\link\overline=false
data\link\underline=true
data\link\strikeout=false
data\link\waveUnderline=false
data\link\fontFamily=
data\link\pointSize=0
data\align-ampersand\priority=-1
data\align-ampersand\bold=true
data\align-ampersand\italic=false
data\align-ampersand\overline=false
data\align-ampersand\underline=false
data\align-ampersand\strikeout=false
data\align-ampersand\waveUnderline=false
data\align-ampersand\foreground=#dc322f
data\align-ampersand\fontFamily=
data\align-ampersand\pointSize=0
data\verbatim\priority=-1
data\verbatim\bold=false
data\verbatim\italic=false
data\verbatim\overline=false
data\verbatim\underline=false
data\verbatim\strikeout=false
data\verbatim\waveUnderline=false
data\verbatim\fontFamily=
data\verbatim\pointSize=0
data\picture\priority=-1
data\picture\bold=false
data\picture\italic=false
data\picture\overline=false
data\picture\underline=false
data\picture\strikeout=false
data\picture\waveUnderline=false
data\picture\foreground=#aa557f
data\picture\fontFamily=
data\picture\pointSize=0
data\braceMatch\priority=-1
data\braceMatch\bold=true
data\braceMatch\italic=false
data\braceMatch\overline=false
data\braceMatch\underline=false
data\braceMatch\strikeout=false
data\braceMatch\waveUnderline=false
data\braceMatch\foreground=#ffaa00
data\braceMatch\fontFamily=
data\braceMatch\pointSize=0
data\braceMismatch\priority=-1
data\braceMismatch\bold=true
data\braceMismatch\italic=false
data\braceMismatch\overline=false
data\braceMismatch\underline=false
data\braceMismatch\strikeout=false
data\braceMismatch\waveUnderline=false
data\braceMismatch\foreground=#ffff7f
data\braceMismatch\fontFamily=
data\braceMismatch\pointSize=0
data\search\priority=-1
data\search\bold=false
data\search\italic=false
data\search\overline=false
data\search\underline=false
data\search\strikeout=false
data\search\waveUnderline=false
data\search\foreground=#000000
data\search\background=#55aa7f
data\search\fontFamily=
data\search\pointSize=0
data\numbers\priority=-1
data\numbers\bold=false
data\numbers\italic=false
data\numbers\overline=false
data\numbers\underline=false
data\numbers\strikeout=false
data\numbers\waveUnderline=false
data\numbers\foreground=#aaffff
data\numbers\fontFamily=
data\numbers\pointSize=0
data\math-delimiter\priority=-1
data\math-delimiter\bold=true
data\math-delimiter\italic=false
data\math-delimiter\overline=false
data\math-delimiter\underline=false
data\math-delimiter\strikeout=false
data\math-delimiter\waveUnderline=false
data\math-delimiter\foreground=#555500
data\math-delimiter\fontFamily=
data\math-delimiter\pointSize=0
data\text\priority=-1
data\text\bold=false
data\text\italic=false
data\text\overline=false
data\text\underline=false
data\text\strikeout=false
data\text\waveUnderline=false
data\text\fontFamily=
data\text\pointSize=0
data\escapeseq\priority=-1
data\escapeseq\bold=false
data\escapeseq\italic=false
data\escapeseq\overline=false
data\escapeseq\underline=false
data\escapeseq\strikeout=false
data\escapeseq\waveUnderline=false
data\escapeseq\fontFamily=
data\escapeseq\pointSize=0
data\wordRepetition\priority=-1
data\wordRepetition\bold=false
data\wordRepetition\italic=false
data\wordRepetition\overline=false
data\wordRepetition\underline=false
data\wordRepetition\strikeout=false
data\wordRepetition\waveUnderline=true
data\wordRepetition\linescolor=#005500
data\wordRepetition\fontFamily=
data\wordRepetition\pointSize=0
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\priority=-1
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\bold=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\italic=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\overline=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\underline=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\strikeout=false
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\waveUnderline=true
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\linescolor=#005500
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\fontFamily=
data\wordRepetitionLongRange\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\priority=-1
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\bold=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\italic=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\overline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\underline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\waveUnderline=true
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\fontFamily=
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\priority=-1
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\bold=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\italic=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\overline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\underline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\waveUnderline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\fontFamily=
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\priority=-1
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\bold=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\italic=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\overline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\underline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\waveUnderline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\fontFamily=
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\priority=-1
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\bold=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\italic=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\overline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\underline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\waveUnderline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\fontFamily=
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\pointSize=0
data\latexSyntaxMistake\priority=-1
data\latexSyntaxMistake\bold=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\italic=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\overline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\underline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\strikeout=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\waveUnderline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\foreground=#d90003
data\latexSyntaxMistake\linescolor=#d90003
data\latexSyntaxMistake\fontFamily=
data\latexSyntaxMistake\pointSize=0
data\environment\priority=-1
data\environment\bold=true
data\environment\italic=false
data\environment\overline=false
data\environment\underline=false
data\environment\strikeout=false
data\environment\waveUnderline=false
data\environment\foreground=#55ff7f
data\environment\fontFamily=
data\environment\pointSize=0
data\referencePresent\priority=-1
data\referencePresent\bold=false
data\referencePresent\italic=false
data\referencePresent\overline=false
data\referencePresent\underline=false
data\referencePresent\strikeout=false
data\referencePresent\waveUnderline=false
data\referencePresent\foreground=#aaff7f
data\referencePresent\fontFamily=
data\referencePresent\pointSize=0
data\referenceMissing\priority=-1
data\referenceMissing\bold=false
data\referenceMissing\italic=false
data\referenceMissing\overline=false
data\referenceMissing\underline=false
data\referenceMissing\strikeout=false
data\referenceMissing\waveUnderline=false
data\referenceMissing\foreground=#000000
data\referenceMissing\fontFamily=
data\referenceMissing\pointSize=0
data\citationPresent\priority=-1
data\citationPresent\bold=false
data\citationPresent\italic=false
data\citationPresent\overline=false
data\citationPresent\underline=false
data\citationPresent\strikeout=false
data\citationPresent\waveUnderline=false
data\citationPresent\foreground=#aaff7f
data\citationPresent\fontFamily=
data\citationPresent\pointSize=0
data\citationMissing\priority=-1
data\citationMissing\bold=false
data\citationMissing\italic=false
data\citationMissing\overline=false
data\citationMissing\underline=false
data\citationMissing\strikeout=false
data\citationMissing\waveUnderline=true
data\citationMissing\foreground=#aaff7f
data\citationMissing\fontFamily=
data\citationMissing\pointSize=0
data\packagePresent\priority=-1
data\packagePresent\bold=false
data\packagePresent\italic=false
data\packagePresent\overline=false
data\packagePresent\underline=false
data\packagePresent\strikeout=false
data\packagePresent\waveUnderline=false
data\packagePresent\foreground=#aaff7f
data\packagePresent\fontFamily=
data\packagePresent\pointSize=0
data\packageMissing\priority=-1
data\packageMissing\bold=false
data\packageMissing\italic=false
data\packageMissing\overline=false
data\packageMissing\underline=false
data\packageMissing\strikeout=false
data\packageMissing\waveUnderline=true
data\packageMissing\foreground=#aaff7f
data\packageMissing\fontFamily=
data\packageMissing\pointSize=0
data\structure\priority=-1
data\structure\bold=true
data\structure\italic=false
data\structure\overline=false
data\structure\underline=false
data\structure\strikeout=false
data\structure\waveUnderline=false
data\structure\foreground=#fffffa
data\structure\fontFamily=
data\structure\pointSize=0
data\current\priority=-1
data\current\bold=false
data\current\italic=false
data\current\overline=false
data\current\underline=false
data\current\strikeout=false
data\current\waveUnderline=false
data\current\background=#828261
data\current\fontFamily=
data\current\pointSize=2
data\selection\priority=-1
data\selection\bold=false
data\selection\italic=false
data\selection\overline=false
data\selection\underline=false
data\selection\strikeout=false
data\selection\waveUnderline=false
data\selection\background=#bebe5e
data\selection\fontFamily=
data\selection\pointSize=0
data\replacement\priority=-1
data\replacement\bold=false
data\replacement\italic=false
data\replacement\overline=false
data\replacement\underline=false
data\replacement\strikeout=false
data\replacement\waveUnderline=false
data\replacement\fontFamily=
data\replacement\pointSize=0
data\diffDelete\priority=-1
data\diffDelete\bold=false
data\diffDelete\italic=false
data\diffDelete\overline=false
data\diffDelete\underline=false
data\diffDelete\strikeout=true
data\diffDelete\waveUnderline=false
data\diffDelete\fontFamily=
data\diffDelete\pointSize=0
data\diffAdd\priority=-1
data\diffAdd\bold=false
data\diffAdd\italic=false
data\diffAdd\overline=false
data\diffAdd\underline=false
data\diffAdd\strikeout=false
data\diffAdd\waveUnderline=false
data\diffAdd\fontFamily=
data\diffAdd\pointSize=0
data\diffReplace\priority=-1
data\diffReplace\bold=false
data\diffReplace\italic=false
data\diffReplace\overline=false
data\diffReplace\underline=false
data\diffReplace\strikeout=false
data\diffReplace\waveUnderline=false
data\diffReplace\fontFamily=
data\diffReplace\pointSize=0
data\preedit\priority=-1
data\preedit\bold=false
data\preedit\italic=false
data\preedit\overline=false
data\preedit\underline=false
data\preedit\strikeout=false
data\preedit\waveUnderline=false
data\preedit\fontFamily=
data\preedit\pointSize=0
data\dtx%3Amacro\priority=-1
data\dtx%3Amacro\bold=true
data\dtx%3Amacro\italic=false
data\dtx%3Amacro\overline=false
data\dtx%3Amacro\underline=false
data\dtx%3Amacro\strikeout=false
data\dtx%3Amacro\waveUnderline=false
data\dtx%3Amacro\fontFamily=
data\dtx%3Amacro\pointSize=0
data\referenceMultiple\priority=-1
data\referenceMultiple\bold=false
data\referenceMultiple\italic=false
data\referenceMultiple\overline=false
data\referenceMultiple\underline=false
data\referenceMultiple\strikeout=false
data\referenceMultiple\waveUnderline=false
data\referenceMultiple\fontFamily=
data\referenceMultiple\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\linescolor=#aaffff
data\grammarMistake\priority=-1
data\grammarMistake\bold=false
data\grammarMistake\italic=false
data\grammarMistake\overline=false
data\grammarMistake\underline=false
data\grammarMistake\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistake\waveUnderline=true
data\grammarMistake\linescolor=#ffff7f
data\grammarMistake\fontFamily=
data\grammarMistake\pointSize=0
```

Answer (score 6):

I customised TexStudio quite a bit, so I'll share my theme here, in case anyone else likes it.

"Ice and a campfire" theme:

```
[formats]
data\align-ampersand\bold=true
data\align-ampersand\fontFamily=
data\align-ampersand\foreground=#67c9cb
data\align-ampersand\italic=false
data\align-ampersand\overline=false
data\align-ampersand\pointSize=0
data\align-ampersand\priority=-1
data\align-ampersand\strikeout=false
data\align-ampersand\underline=false
data\align-ampersand\waveUnderline=false
data\align-ampersand\wrapAround=false
data\background\background=#36393f
data\background\bold=false
data\background\fontFamily=
data\background\italic=false
data\background\overline=false
data\background\pointSize=0
data\background\priority=-1
data\background\strikeout=false
data\background\underline=false
data\background\waveUnderline=false
data\background\wrapAround=false
data\braceMatch\background=#fdff68
data\braceMatch\bold=true
data\braceMatch\fontFamily=
data\braceMatch\foreground=#c00000
data\braceMatch\italic=false
data\braceMatch\overline=false
data\braceMatch\pointSize=0
data\braceMatch\priority=-1
data\braceMatch\strikeout=false
data\braceMatch\underline=false
data\braceMatch\waveUnderline=false
data\braceMatch\wrapAround=false
data\braceMismatch\background=#b00003
data\braceMismatch\bold=true
data\braceMismatch\fontFamily=
data\braceMismatch\foreground=#ffff7f
data\braceMismatch\italic=false
data\braceMismatch\overline=false
data\braceMismatch\pointSize=0
data\braceMismatch\priority=-1
data\braceMismatch\strikeout=false
data\braceMismatch\underline=false
data\braceMismatch\waveUnderline=false
data\braceMismatch\wrapAround=false
data\citationPresent\bold=false
data\citationPresent\fontFamily=
data\citationPresent\foreground=#51c878
data\citationPresent\italic=false
data\citationPresent\overline=false
data\citationPresent\pointSize=0
data\citationPresent\priority=-1
data\citationPresent\strikeout=false
data\citationPresent\underline=false
data\citationPresent\waveUnderline=false
data\citationPresent\wrapAround=false
data\comment\bold=false
data\comment\fontFamily=
data\comment\foreground=#aeaeae
data\comment\italic=false
data\comment\overline=false
data\comment\pointSize=0
data\comment\priority=-1
data\comment\strikeout=false
data\comment\underline=false
data\comment\waveUnderline=false
data\comment\wrapAround=false
data\commentTodo\bold=false
data\commentTodo\fontFamily=
data\commentTodo\foreground=#6c71c4
data\commentTodo\italic=false
data\commentTodo\overline=false
data\commentTodo\pointSize=0
data\commentTodo\priority=-1
data\commentTodo\strikeout=false
data\commentTodo\underline=false
data\commentTodo\waveUnderline=false
data\commentTodo\wrapAround=false
data\current\background=#0b586c
data\current\bold=false
data\current\fontFamily=
data\current\italic=false
data\current\overline=false
data\current\pointSize=0
data\current\priority=-1
data\current\strikeout=false
data\current\underline=false
data\current\waveUnderline=false
data\current\wrapAround=false
data\diffAdd\bold=false
data\diffAdd\fontFamily=
data\diffAdd\italic=false
data\diffAdd\overline=false
data\diffAdd\pointSize=0
data\diffAdd\priority=-1
data\diffAdd\strikeout=false
data\diffAdd\underline=false
data\diffAdd\waveUnderline=false
data\diffAdd\wrapAround=false
data\diffDelete\bold=false
data\diffDelete\fontFamily=
data\diffDelete\italic=false
data\diffDelete\overline=false
data\diffDelete\pointSize=0
data\diffDelete\priority=-1
data\diffDelete\strikeout=true
data\diffDelete\underline=false
data\diffDelete\waveUnderline=false
data\diffDelete\wrapAround=false
data\diffReplace\bold=false
data\diffReplace\fontFamily=
data\diffReplace\italic=false
data\diffReplace\overline=false
data\diffReplace\pointSize=0
data\diffReplace\priority=-1
data\diffReplace\strikeout=false
data\diffReplace\underline=false
data\diffReplace\waveUnderline=false
data\diffReplace\wrapAround=false
data\environment\bold=false
data\environment\fontFamily=
data\environment\foreground=#b8baff
data\environment\italic=false
data\environment\overline=false
data\environment\pointSize=0
data\environment\priority=-1
data\environment\strikeout=false
data\environment\underline=false
data\environment\waveUnderline=false
data\environment\wrapAround=false
data\escapeseq\bold=false
data\escapeseq\fontFamily=
data\escapeseq\italic=false
data\escapeseq\overline=false
data\escapeseq\pointSize=0
data\escapeseq\priority=-1
data\escapeseq\strikeout=false
data\escapeseq\underline=false
data\escapeseq\waveUnderline=false
data\escapeseq\wrapAround=false
data\extra-keyword\bold=true
data\extra-keyword\fontFamily=
data\extra-keyword\foreground=#4d74ff
data\extra-keyword\italic=false
data\extra-keyword\overline=false
data\extra-keyword\pointSize=0
data\extra-keyword\priority=-1
data\extra-keyword\strikeout=false
data\extra-keyword\underline=false
data\extra-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\extra-keyword\wrapAround=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\bold=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\fontFamily=
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\italic=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\overline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\priority=-1
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\underline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\waveUnderline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial1\wrapAround=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\bold=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\fontFamily=
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\italic=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\overline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\priority=-1
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\underline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\waveUnderline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial2\wrapAround=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\bold=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\fontFamily=
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\italic=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\overline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\priority=-1
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\underline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\waveUnderline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial3\wrapAround=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\bold=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\fontFamily=
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\italic=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\overline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\pointSize=0
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\priority=-1
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\strikeout=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\underline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\waveUnderline=false
data\grammarMistakeSpecial4\wrapAround=false
data\keyword\bold=false
data\keyword\fontFamily=
data\keyword\foreground=#67c9cb
data\keyword\italic=false
data\keyword\overline=false
data\keyword\pointSize=0
data\keyword\priority=-1
data\keyword\strikeout=false
data\keyword\underline=false
data\keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\keyword\wrapAround=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\bold=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\fontFamily=
data\latexSyntaxMistake\italic=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\linescolor=#d90003
data\latexSyntaxMistake\overline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\pointSize=0
data\latexSyntaxMistake\priority=-1
data\latexSyntaxMistake\strikeout=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\underline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\waveUnderline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\wrapAround=false
data\line%3Abadbox\bold=false
data\line%3Abadbox\fontFamily=
data\line%3Abadbox\italic=false
data\line%3Abadbox\overline=false
data\line%3Abadbox\pointSize=0
data\line%3Abadbox\priority=-1
data\line%3Abadbox\strikeout=false
data\line%3Abadbox\underline=false
data\line%3Abadbox\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Abadbox\wrapAround=false
data\line%3Aerror\bold=false
data\line%3Aerror\fontFamily=
data\line%3Aerror\italic=false
data\line%3Aerror\overline=false
data\line%3Aerror\pointSize=0
data\line%3Aerror\priority=-1
data\line%3Aerror\strikeout=false
data\line%3Aerror\underline=false
data\line%3Aerror\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Aerror\wrapAround=false
data\line%3Awarning\bold=false
data\line%3Awarning\fontFamily=
data\line%3Awarning\italic=false
data\line%3Awarning\overline=false
data\line%3Awarning\pointSize=0
data\line%3Awarning\priority=-1
data\line%3Awarning\strikeout=false
data\line%3Awarning\underline=false
data\line%3Awarning\waveUnderline=false
data\line%3Awarning\wrapAround=false
data\link\bold=false
data\link\fontFamily=
data\link\italic=false
data\link\overline=false
data\link\pointSize=0
data\link\priority=-1
data\link\strikeout=false
data\link\underline=true
data\link\waveUnderline=false
data\link\wrapAround=false
data\math-delimiter\bold=true
data\math-delimiter\fontFamily=
data\math-delimiter\foreground=#7fe64c
data\math-delimiter\italic=false
data\math-delimiter\overline=false
data\math-delimiter\pointSize=0
data\math-delimiter\priority=-1
data\math-delimiter\strikeout=false
data\math-delimiter\underline=false
data\math-delimiter\waveUnderline=false
data\math-delimiter\wrapAround=false
data\math-keyword\bold=false
data\math-keyword\fontFamily=
data\math-keyword\foreground=#7fe64c
data\math-keyword\italic=false
data\math-keyword\overline=false
data\math-keyword\pointSize=0
data\math-keyword\priority=-1
data\math-keyword\strikeout=false
data\math-keyword\underline=false
data\math-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\math-keyword\wrapAround=false
data\normal\bold=false
data\normal\fontFamily=
data\normal\foreground=#f8f8f8
data\normal\italic=false
data\normal\overline=false
data\normal\pointSize=0
data\normal\priority=-1
data\normal\strikeout=false
data\normal\underline=false
data\normal\waveUnderline=false
data\normal\wrapAround=false
data\numbers\bold=false
data\numbers\fontFamily=
data\numbers\foreground=#7fe64c
data\numbers\italic=false
data\numbers\overline=false
data\numbers\pointSize=0
data\numbers\priority=-1
data\numbers\strikeout=false
data\numbers\underline=false
data\numbers\waveUnderline=false
data\numbers\wrapAround=false
data\picture\bold=false
data\picture\fontFamily=
data\picture\foreground=#c93682
data\picture\italic=false
data\picture\overline=false
data\picture\pointSize=0
data\picture\priority=-1
data\picture\strikeout=false
data\picture\underline=false
data\picture\waveUnderline=false
data\picture\wrapAround=false
data\preedit\bold=false
data\preedit\fontFamily=
data\preedit\italic=false
data\preedit\overline=false
data\preedit\pointSize=0
data\preedit\priority=-1
data\preedit\strikeout=false
data\preedit\underline=false
data\preedit\waveUnderline=false
data\preedit\wrapAround=false
data\referenceMultiple\bold=false
data\referenceMultiple\fontFamily=
data\referenceMultiple\foreground=#51c878
data\referenceMultiple\italic=false
data\referenceMultiple\overline=false
data\referenceMultiple\pointSize=0
data\referenceMultiple\priority=-1
data\referenceMultiple\strikeout=false
data\referenceMultiple\underline=false
data\referenceMultiple\waveUnderline=true
data\referenceMultiple\wrapAround=false
data\referencePresent\bold=false
data\referencePresent\fontFamily=
data\referencePresent\foreground=#51c878
data\referencePresent\italic=false
data\referencePresent\overline=false
data\referencePresent\pointSize=0
data\referencePresent\priority=-1
data\referencePresent\strikeout=false
data\referencePresent\underline=false
data\referencePresent\waveUnderline=false
data\referencePresent\wrapAround=false
data\replacement\bold=false
data\replacement\fontFamily=
data\replacement\italic=false
data\replacement\overline=false
data\replacement\pointSize=0
data\replacement\priority=-1
data\replacement\strikeout=false
data\replacement\underline=false
data\replacement\waveUnderline=false
data\replacement\wrapAround=false
data\search\bold=false
data\search\fontFamily=
data\search\foreground=#000000
data\search\italic=false
data\search\overline=false
data\search\pointSize=0
data\search\priority=-1
data\search\strikeout=false
data\search\underline=false
data\search\waveUnderline=false
data\search\wrapAround=false
data\selection\background=#aaffff
data\selection\bold=false
data\selection\fontFamily=
data\selection\italic=false
data\selection\overline=false
data\selection\pointSize=0
data\selection\priority=-1
data\selection\strikeout=false
data\selection\underline=false
data\selection\waveUnderline=false
data\selection\wrapAround=false
data\structure\bold=true
data\structure\fontFamily=
data\structure\foreground=#91e9ff
data\structure\italic=false
data\structure\overline=false
data\structure\pointSize=0
data\structure\priority=-1
data\structure\strikeout=false
data\structure\underline=false
data\structure\waveUnderline=false
data\structure\wrapAround=false
data\text\bold=false
data\text\fontFamily=
data\text\italic=false
data\text\overline=false
data\text\pointSize=0
data\text\priority=-1
data\text\strikeout=false
data\text\underline=false
data\text\waveUnderline=false
data\text\wrapAround=false
data\verbatim\bold=false
data\verbatim\fontFamily=
data\verbatim\italic=false
data\verbatim\overline=false
data\verbatim\pointSize=0
data\verbatim\priority=-1
data\verbatim\strikeout=false
data\verbatim\underline=false
data\verbatim\waveUnderline=false
data\verbatim\wrapAround=false
version=1.0
```

[image: Example]

The text and (incomplete) tikzpicture is from an old script of mine (very old, ignore the newbie code), I just put it in as an example for what the colours look like in this scheme.