# loading .texsprofile into TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

I'm keen to use the fantastic dark themes from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/anyone-willing-to-share-his-her-custom-dark-theme-for-texstudio) but I can't get TexStudio to actually 'read' the colours from the `.texsprofile` file.

I'm using `TexStudio 2.6.2` on Linux Mint 16.

I also have a TexStudio installation on Windows 7 and I save the `.texsprofile` file by doing `Options > Save Settings...` But when I do `Options > Load Settings...` in my Linux installation, nothing changes. The colours are exactly as they were before!

Can anyone help me get the themes from the above-mentioned question into my TexStudio installation?

Comment: I’d say, the profile file isn’t complete. Try to add `[General]`<line break>`IniMode=true` in the first two lines, does this help?

Comment: Hi @Tobi, thanks, but those lines are already present!

Comment: Hm, sorry … try to add `Macros\0=some Macro, %SCRIPT\neditor.insertText(\"%\\n\"), , ` (line ends with a space) in the `[texmaker]` with a text editor and then import the profile agin. Do you get a new macro in the macro menu? Btw. did sou restart the app after importing the file?

Comment: Oh! I'm a fool. I needed to restart TexMaker before the profile was applied. This is weird! Perhaps there's a message needed here... If you make this the answer to the question, I'll accept it.

Comment: try close textstudio and init..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: The profile is read only once when TeXstudio opens. Any changes that are made while it is running take affect after restarting the app. I suggest to quit TeXstudio before changing things in the profile manually. Otherwise manual changes and changes done by TeXstudio (e.g. adding a file to the “latest files” list) may interfere with each other and give bad results.