# Cannot load .txsprofile into Texstudio

Tags: texstudio, editors

I am trying to use the question: [How can I set a dark theme in TeXstudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/anyone-willing-to-share-his-her-custom-dark-theme-for-texstudio) to load themes created by other users. Unfortunately there are no changes. I do this the following way

1. Choose `Options -> Save profile`
2. I make changes in the file according to the mentioned question under heading `[Formats]`.
3. I open Texstudio and choose `Options -> Load profile` and load the changed file.
4. I quit Texstudio and open it once again.
5. I make a new document but no changes are observed.

Am I doing everything fine? Do I miss any step? What can cause the problem of not changing?
the settings?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [loading .texsprofile into TexStudio](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160063/loading-texsprofile-into-texstudio)

Comment: Not a duplicate - I used the solution from the question you've posted - unfortunately without success - maybe the problem is with the fact that I use portable version, but frankly speaking I cannot see the link :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the import. As a workaround do the following. Just copy the [formats] section to `texstudio.ini` replacing an existing section if there is already one. You need to do it while TXS is closed. Otherwise it won't recognize your changes and would overwrite them when exiting.