# Any Sublime txsprofile for TexStudio?

Tags: texstudio, sublime-text

Has anyone created TexStudio txsprofile based on Sublime 3.0 colour schema?

I truly appreciate sharing. I switched from Sublime to TexStudio and need such profile!

Comment: There are some dark schemes in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/anyone-willing-to-share-his-her-custom-dark-theme-for-texstudio at least.

Answer (score 2):

I recreated the Theme from Sublime on the basis of the Solarized Profile. Using ColorPix form ColorSchemer was quite helpful for picking the right colours right out of SublimeText.

Since StackExchange won't let me post it because of the character-limitation you can find the config [here](http://pastebin.com/sUeueqUj).

[image]