# Texstudio and color scheme

Tags: color, texstudio

I try to use texstudio for mac. How can i change the color scheme? I found this discussion [How can I set a dark theme in TeXstudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/anyone-willing-to-share-his-her-custom-dark-theme-for-texstudio), but i do not know how use this color scheme

Comment: [My answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108599/21891) contains instructions for applying those settings. Did you try that?

Comment: Sorry, where? i don't see them

Comment: *To apply those setting, substitute the following code for the code currently under the "[formats]" heading in your TeXstudio settings file (.texsprofile); then load that settings file in TeXstudio. You will have to restart TeXstudio for the changed to be effective.*

Comment: In Windows I don't have this file.  (And of course I've searched also for hidden ones)

Comment: It is a 3 years old questions.