# How do I change color settings in TeXStudio?

Tags: texstudio

I realize this may be a stupid question, but I can't find the answer anywhere. Where is the `.texsprofile` file for TeXStudio? If it doesn't exist by default, where should I place it when I create it? I'm trying to use one of the themes in [this article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/anyone-willing-to-share-his-her-custom-dark-theme-for-texstudio), but  I can't figure out how to make it work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Windows, or linux or mac?

Answer (score 12):

This is only for windows.

You have to place .texsprofile in `C:\Users\<your name>\AppData\Roaming\texstudio`where `<your name>` is to be read as it is in your computer. Then in `TeXstudio` go to `Options` → `Load Profile`

[image]

Clicking `Load Profile` opens this window:

[image]

Select the profile, click `Open` and restart TeXstudio.

Comment: You can see some of the profile given in the linked answer stored in the above screen shot. :)

Comment: To add to this answer, if you have some particular settings (e.g., personalized shortcuts) and you want to keep them, you can save your current profile, add the syntax highlighting data from that link under the `[format]` section in your profile file and then load it back as Harish has shown.

Comment: Following same steps, you'll find that the `*.texsprofile` files are stored in `~/.config/texstudio/` on Unix.

Comment: The `.texsprofile` file mentioned here is actually **`.txsprofile`** file. It is also noticeable in the second screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The official FAQ **"where are the settings stored"** help page can be found here

https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#where-are-the-settings-stored

NOTE **By default the *.txsprofile settings** are supposed to be in the same  folder with (alongside) the TeXstudio.ini plus other config files including any system theme **customising *.qss** see [How to change color of scrollbar?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468516/how-to-change-color-of-scrollbar/468650#468650)

> "The settings are stored in a file called texstudio.ini. The default
>   paths are:
>
> • **Linux/Unix/Mac:** ~/.config/texstudio/texstudio.ini
>   • **Windows:** %APPDATA%\texstudio\texstudio.ini
>   • **Portable Version:** config/texstudio.ini relative to the TeXstudio executable.
>       (Pre 2.12.: located directly in the directory of the TeXstudio executable.)
>
> You can find out the actual path via

```
Help -> Check LaTeX Installation.
```

> The resulting report contains a section called "Setting file".
>   **Note: TeXstudio has to be closed while editing texstudio.ini. Otherwise** the **changes** won't have any effect and **will be overwritten** when TeXstudio is closed."

Comment: It would be nice to not only post a link but also include the essential information in your answer. This way your answer will still be helpful to future users in case the link is no longer available.

Comment: @samcarter Done, was that your down vote?

Comment: Thanks for your edit! No, the downvote was not from me and I just upvoted to compensate it :)

Comment: @samcarter I was surprised and quakers to suggest it , thanks for the heads up and consideration