# Change background colour of toolbars in TeXstudio

Tags: color, texstudio, windows

With [How do I change color settings in TeXStudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211356/how-do-i-change-color-settings-in-texstudio) and [How can I set a dark theme in TeXstudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/anyone-willing-to-share-his-her-custom-dark-theme-for-texstudio) I managed to change the colour of the editor (in this case to a darker theme to prevent eye strain).

Now I would like to change the colour of

- The toolbars
- The Structure and Message / Log File menus
- The line numbers at the left of the editor
- The Line, Visual column, Text column counter below the editor

I already tried the advanced options from Options -> Configure TeXstudio.

Comment: I hope at some point TeXStudio will support this customization without relying on system configurations. Meanwhile, in Windows 10 you can use any of the existing High Contrast themes or even override your own one. [This link](https://superuser.com/questions/1002847/how-to-change-default-window-background-color-in-windows-10) explains how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Toolbars: At "Options -> General -> Appearance -> Color Scheme" you can choose between the following two settings:

- "Classic": Use native system settings.
- "Modern": A proprietary design with dark and more flat toolbars (color is not changable).

Other elements: All these elements use the native system settings of your Desktop design (If you change the desktop design, you may need to restart TeXstudio so that these changes take effect).

- The Structure and Message / Log File menus
- The line numbers at the left of the editor
- The Line, Visual column, Text column counter below the editor