# Change background colour of toolbars in TeXstudio mac

Tags: color, texstudio, mac

Have the same question as posted here

[Change background colour of toolbars in TeXstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215373/change-background-colour-of-toolbars-in-texstudio)

just that I'm on an OSX device

---

With [How do I change color settings in TeXStudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211356/how-do-i-change-color-settings-in-texstudio) and [How can I set a dark theme in TeXstudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/anyone-willing-to-share-his-her-custom-dark-theme-for-texstudio) I managed to change the colour of the editor (in this case to a darker theme to prevent eye strain).

Now I would like to change the colour of

- The toolbars
- The Structure and Message / Log File menus
- The line numbers at the left of the editor
- The Line, Visual column, Text column counter below the editor

I already tried the advanced options from Options -> Configure TeXstudio.

Answer (score 1):

The GUI is not fully customizable. The only choice you have is `Options -> General -> Appearance -> Color Scheme` which let's you choose between OS-style toolbars ("Classic") and custom dark toolbars ("Modern"). All other colors are derived from the color sheme of your desktop (not sure how much configurability OSX offers there).

With advanced options enabled there's an additional checkbox `Ignore most system colors` next to the above setting. It overwrites some of the system settings. But its main intention is to resolve possible conflicts between the "Modern" color scheme and system settings.

Answer (score 0):

TeXstudio is built on QT which acts as a canvas between the editor settings and the system settings. There are ways to change the underlying colours by adding a "stylesheet" so I have shown the example for changing the scrollbars in this answer 
[image]

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468650/170109

It is possible to change much more but you will need to follow the links to brew your own or find a larger set of changes.