# How to change background color in the editor side in LaTeX?

Tags: texstudio, editors

I want to change background color in the editor side like in the example picture.

How can I do?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Which is your editor?

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new in Tex.SX it is really wonderful... Thanks again.

Comment: `Option --> Configure TeXstudio --> Syntax highlighting` (I don't know if this is the exact naming because I have the Italian version) and then choose what you want to change and with which color. For more advanced setting see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211356/how-do-i-change-color-settings-in-texstudio) or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texstudio).

Comment: Thank you very much for your helping. (Syntax highlighting is the exact name in English version)

Comment: You could be interested in [How can I set a dark theme in TeXstudio?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108315/64454) - even if listed themes are, indeed, darker than your picture. (+ [How do I change color settings in TeXStudio?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211356/64454))

Comment: No, thanks :) I just wanted to learn how can I highlight some lines in the editor side like in the picture I loaded.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Do you wantto answer or do we have a matching duplicate sitting around?

Comment: @Johannes_B Since the answers ebo and me have linked exceed the needs of the OP, I'll post an answer, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just go to
`Options --> Configure TeXstudio --> Syntax highlighting` and choose what you want to change and with which color.

For more advanced setting see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211356/how-do-i-change-color-settings-in-texstudio) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texstudio).

Comment: Can you tell me how to change the colour of some codes in the editor screen of MikTex. Your answer is not applicable to MikTex. Thank you.

Comment: @Hany the question concerns TeXstudio. MiKTeX is not an editor, it is a distribution. If you have a different question, ask another one.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you are wondering were the green-background lines in your picture are coming from, they are due to comments in capital letters (and a few others).

Try a line with

```
% TODO buy more rubber ducks :)
```

see http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION14