# TexStudio Stock Theme

Tags: texstudio, themes

I just applied one of these themes:
[How can I set a dark theme in TeXstudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/anyone-willing-to-share-his-her-custom-dark-theme-for-texstudio)

How can I switch back to the stock theme?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.texsprofile` file? Be sure to make a backup copy!

Comment: Yes, I hadn't had one, so I created one for the dark theme, applied it and then after deleted the dark theme, but I still have the theme applied in TexStudio ...

Comment: Delete the offending lines from your `.texprofile` file, then close and relaunch TeXStudio? Those settings get applied when the app is starting.

Comment: I allready created an empty file and applied it. A restart didn't worked.

Comment: Have you tried to change either "style" or "color" in "Options / Configure TeXStudio / General" ? That should bring back the default settings.

Comment: Tried it in additional, but this doesn't worked. The best way is to erase the additional lines in the texstudio.ini File under [formats], like Tim Hoffmann allready wrote. This worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default settings are built in. They apply if no changes are made to the respective format. Format changes are part of the general settings in [texstudio.ini](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-the-settings-stored).

To remove all changed formats, simply delete the section `[formats]` in texstudio.ini (Make sure TXS are closed while you do so, otherwise your modifications won't take effect and will be overwritten when TXS closes).

Comment: Any plans for a built-in dark theme, like in Texmaker? According to your [issue tracker](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/317/), such a feature is low on your priority list, but [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/anyone-willing-to-share-his-her-custom-dark-theme-for-texstudio) has been viewed close to 8k times, which seems to indicate a strong interest in a built-in dark theme...

Comment: Thanks for the help. Worked very well :)
I agree with Jubobs, a build in dark-theme would be very very nice and also helpful.