# How do I change the colors of the application interface in TexStudio?

Tags: texstudio, color-profile

I understand how to change the colors of the editor itself ( as in the link: [How can I set a dark theme in TeXstudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/anyone-willing-to-share-his-her-custom-dark-theme-for-texstudio) ) but now I want to change the application interface from white with black font to black with green font. Do I still use .texprofile? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can study the options of those custom themes, isn't hard to get it, but you should start to play with the color configuration, is funny. In the worst scene you could uninstall and reinstall it again.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Isn't this controlled by your window manager settings? At least some of it must be, so it might depend exactly which bits you are concerned with. That is the 'outside' bits will be. The 'inside' bits may be handled for the application or for applications based on a particular GUI kit. At least, that's how things seem to work here.