# Is it possible to customize the colors of TexStudio itself (menus, toolbars, etc)?

Tags: color, texstudio

So, to make it abundantly clear what I am asking for, here is an example picture edited (poorly) in a drawing software:

[image]

At left, you can see my current TexStudio look: the are where real text is indeed entered had its colors properly customized with a `.txsprofile` object. However, the menu toolbar, the tabs area and so on are still colored in light-gray, while I would like them to have a darker look (as in the image to the right).

Is it possible to achieve that somehow?

I am aware that plenty of questions have been asked here and elsewhere on the topic of TexStudio's colors. For example:

- [How do I change the colors of the application interface in TexStudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215928/how-do-i-change-the-colors-of-the-application-interface-in-texstudio)
- [Dark theme for Texstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275534/dark-theme-for-texstudio?rq=1)
- [How can I set a dark theme in TeXstudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texstudio)
- [How do I change color settings in TeXStudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211356/how-do-i-change-color-settings-in-texstudio)

However, none of them really addressed the main point at hand: how to customize the colors of TexStudio's menus, toolbars, etc (not the colors of the text-editor part of TexStudio). The colors of the text-editor of TexStudio can be modified directly at the Syntax Highlighting options in the `Tools>Configurations` menu. However, rarely something is said about the other parts of TexStudio.

When a question pops up about this, it gets either no answers or very low-detailed reactions. For instance:

- [How do I change the colors of the application interface in TexStudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215928/how-do-i-change-the-colors-of-the-application-interface-in-texstudio)
- [Change background colour of toolbars in TeXstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215373/change-background-colour-of-toolbars-in-texstudio)

I realize that what TexStudio is doing is probably just retrieving the operational system color for it's menus, tool-bars and such. My question is whether there is anyway to bypass that and customize such colors.

Comment: At least some of the elements you're asking about are not part of TS at all. They are part of the window(s) which typically contain TS display. Those are controlled by your window manager. (You can see this most clearly if your window manager crashes and you are left with just the innards and no window controls.) TS doesn't control this. If it turns out it can, you should complain loudly because you really do not want applications to be able to do that!

Comment: @cfr Thanks for you comment. I see what you mean, but I am not asking whether TS can change the system UI colors, which indeed should stay impossible for any application. However any application can opt to use the OS GUI or implement a new one, and if adopting the OS GUI, it can allow more or less customization on top of the OS GUI.

Comment: But, typically, the window is not part of the application. At least where I am, the window itself is simply not something TS controls or could control. That's why it can disappear without TS being affected.

Comment: Some of it may be based on one of the common frameworks (GTK or whatever). If so, you can often control aspects of applications using its building blocks. If your desktop environment or window manager or whatever isn't built on it, you can probably control it separately or it may permit you more fine-grained control.) And, of course, you could edit the source code of TS and change it yourself.

Comment: Perhaps not a real customization as you would like it, but in TS preferences, you can choose the style and color theme of TS. Configure TexStudio >General > Appearence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeXstudio is built on QT which acts as a canvas between the editor settings and the system settings. There are ways to change the underlying colours by adding a "stylesheet" so I have shown the example for changing the scrollbars in this answer 
[image]

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468650/170109

It is possible to change much more but you will need to follow the links to brew your own or find a larger set of changes.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [this response](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215841/24770):

> Other elements: All these elements use the native system settings of your Desktop design.

This does also include the menus and the editor tab bar. There are no settings within TXS that control these colors. The colors are simply inherited from your desktop theme.