# How to change texmaker's theme?

Tags: texmaker, themes, ide

I downloaded texmaker and I would like to change the theme, because it hurt my eyes. From a previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/anyone-willing-to-share-his-her-custom-dark-theme-for-texstudio) I found this theme:

```
[formats]
version=1.0
data\normal\priority=-1
data\normal\bold=false
data\normal\italic=false
data\normal\overline=false
data\normal\underline=false
data\normal\strikeout=false
data\normal\waveUnderline=false
data\normal\foreground=#ffffff
data\normal\background=#000518
data\normal\fontFamily=Courier 10 Pitch
data\normal\pointSize=0
data\comment\priority=-1
data\comment\bold=false
data\comment\italic=false
data\comment\overline=false
data\comment\underline=false
data\comment\strikeout=false
data\comment\waveUnderline=false
data\comment\foreground=#9a9a9a
data\comment\fontFamily=
data\comment\pointSize=0
data\keyword\priority=-1
data\keyword\bold=false
data\keyword\italic=false
data\keyword\overline=false
data\keyword\underline=false
data\keyword\strikeout=false
data\keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\keyword\foreground=#4e9dec
data\keyword\fontFamily=
data\keyword\pointSize=0
data\extra-keyword\priority=-1
data\extra-keyword\bold=false
data\extra-keyword\italic=false
data\extra-keyword\overline=false
data\extra-keyword\underline=false
data\extra-keyword\strikeout=false
data\extra-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\extra-keyword\foreground=#fff700
data\extra-keyword\fontFamily=
data\extra-keyword\pointSize=0
data\math-keyword\priority=-1
data\math-keyword\bold=true
data\math-keyword\italic=false
data\math-keyword\overline=false
data\math-keyword\underline=false
data\math-keyword\strikeout=false
data\math-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\math-keyword\foreground=#488700
data\math-keyword\fontFamily=
data\math-keyword\pointSize=0
data\search\priority=-1
data\search\bold=false
data\search\italic=false
data\search\overline=false
data\search\underline=false
data\search\strikeout=false
data\search\waveUnderline=false
data\search\foreground=#55ffff
data\search\background=#ff00ff
data\search\fontFamily=
data\search\pointSize=0
data\math-delimiter\priority=-1
data\math-delimiter\bold=true
data\math-delimiter\italic=false
data\math-delimiter\overline=false
data\math-delimiter\underline=false
data\math-delimiter\strikeout=false
data\math-delimiter\waveUnderline=false
data\math-delimiter\foreground=#b90003
data\math-delimiter\fontFamily=
data\math-delimiter\pointSize=0
data\latexSyntaxMistake\priority=-1
data\latexSyntaxMistake\bold=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\italic=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\overline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\underline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\strikeout=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\waveUnderline=true
data\latexSyntaxMistake\foreground=#da0003
data\latexSyntaxMistake\fontFamily=
data\latexSyntaxMistake\pointSize=0
data\environment\priority=-1
data\environment\bold=true
data\environment\italic=false
data\environment\overline=false
data\environment\underline=false
data\environment\strikeout=false
data\environment\waveUnderline=false
data\environment\foreground=#aaaaaa
data\environment\fontFamily=
data\environment\pointSize=0
data\structure\priority=-1
data\structure\bold=true
data\structure\italic=false
data\structure\overline=false
data\structure\underline=false
data\structure\strikeout=false
data\structure\waveUnderline=false
data\structure\foreground=#cfffd3
data\structure\fontFamily=
data\structure\pointSize=0
```

How can I set this theme in Texmaker?.

Comment: Texmaker is not Texstudio

Comment: Now you can go to options->configur texmaker than to editor (icon) and than there is 2 bottons dark them and default them clic dark and choise what you like as colors

Comment: On Gnome shell 4x. Default theme set to light and Texmaker keeps showing the dark theme.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the question you refer to is intended for TeXstudio http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/, not for TeXmaker. TeXstudio is a fork of TeXmaker which offers some extra functionality, but in essence is very similar to TeXmaker. If you want to change the theme easily according to the referred question, install TeXstudio and the proposed solutions will work for you.

Opinion based: I switched from TeXmaker to TeXstudio and I find it more functional and more customizable.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how to change to that particular theme, but an easy option is the following:

> `Options > Configure Texmaker > Editor`

In the "Colors" section you can click on *dark theme*.

If the standard one doesn't suit you, you can also customize it.

Answer (score 2):

A easy way to access your .ini file options>manage settings file>save a copy

This creates a file and allows you to save it anywhere you like. You can then manipulate this file use [this page as reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texstudio) copying and pasting which is what I did.

From there options>manage settings file>replace settings file by new one(one that you manipulated)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration file for TeXmaker called 'texmaker.ini'. It can be found in the installation directory of your TeXmaker. I do not know if you could simply add the settings above, but maybe you'll find the corresponding settings in the existing file.