# texstudio non-english text is black

Tags: color, texstudio

I'm trying to change my color scheme and used [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126083/32310). My document is in persian so I downloaded [this spell checker dictionary](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/persian-spellchecker-dictionary) from OpenOffice website and also in texstudio changed he dictionary default language to farsi. Now it recognizes the persian text and doesn't mark it as spelling error but the text color is black and doesn't follow the 'normal color' in color settings. Is this a bug?

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}
این یک متن نمونه است.
\end{document}
```

'normal color' is set to white but this code appears like this (whit the text black):
[image]

Comment: I thought you meant the PDF, my bad. :D I suppose the code is not important. I don't have TexStudio but did this happen after you installed the spell checker?

Comment: What is the color setting for `\normal\foreground`?

Comment: data\normal\foreground=#ffffff

Comment: Looks like a bug. You may submit it to https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/. When you do so, please provide a complete minimal example including your color scheme.