# customize syntax highlighting, TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I wanted to adjust some of the colours of my TeXstudio editor. I am able to customise a lot but there is one thing that I haven't been able to find:

'the (background) colour of selected lines'.

So for example here in tex.stackexchange this colour is simply light blue (try to select some lines). Is this one simply missing in the list or should I look somewhere else?

Thanks in advance!
AYK

Comment: Actually, it can be done, programmatically. See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texstudio

Comment: It is possible via qt style sheet: [Color of marked Text in TeXStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/428347/117534)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not configurable within TeXstudio. TeXstudio uses the highlight color of the desktop environment. You would have to change your desktop color settings.