# Color of marked Text in TeXStudio

Tags: texstudio, syntax-highlighting

I created a darker theme for TeXStudio and have problems with the
color of the text when I mark it with the cursor:

[image: Color of marked Text]

The first line is marked and I cannot change its color. 
I searched every line in the settings, but I don´t find it.
Maybe you have an idea if it is possible?

Niklas

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but I think TXS takes this from your OS settings and I don't think it's in the default TXS settings. You can  try playing around with QSS stylesheets instead.

Comment: It is using the OS settings, but I don´t want the color of TeXStudio highlights in whole os. Do you have a idea how to change it with QSS stylesheets? First try with `QTextEdit { selection-background-color: rgb(140, 90, 64) }` did not work.

Comment: `QWidget {
    selection-background-color: #db1c49;
    selection-color: #eff0f1;
}`?

Comment: This works! Thank you! Maybe you add this as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The colour of the selection is set by your OS settings by default in TXS.
As of now (TXS version 2.12.8), the option to change the colour of this element is not available in the general settings of TXS, I believe.

The solution now is to use QSS stylesheets, discussed partially in the [project Github thread](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/45#issuecomment-368301279).

Basically, create a file `stylesheet.qss`, and place it in your TXS settings folder.
Paste this in:

```
QWidget {
    selection-background-color: #db1c49;
    selection-color: #eff0f1;
}
```

and restart TXS.

### Note:

- Change the colours as you see fit. `selection-background-color` controls the highlight colour (now red), and `selection-color` is the colour of the words (now white).
- This also affects other elements in TXS, since this affects *all* QWidgets. There are ways to localize this I'm guessing, but I'm no expert in this regard.

[image]