# How can I change color of background and marked text in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

As default, the background color in the TexStudio editor is white and the text you have marked to work on (i.e. were the cursor is) is light blue/gray. Is it possible to reverse that?

EDIT: I am seeking a solution for non-techies.

Comment: For editor background colour, you can just change it in the settings (see Max's link). For marked text colour, use Qt style sheet: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/428347/117534

Comment: To be honest, I don't know if that makes it a duplicate. It does not to me, since I am seeking a solution that does not require high technical skills and insight. Perhaps my question ought to include 'easy' for a non-techie...

Comment: Those two answers are the only way to achieve what you want. Modifying the look of the application is not a core feature of TXS: it's just an aesthetic. So admittedly, it's not the most user-friendly interface, but that's the (only) way it is right now. Raise an issue on the TeXstudio project github page to make these features 'more user friendly' if you so wish, but it's unlikely the devs will entertain it imo.

Comment: @troy, thanks for your reply. Even it did not solve my problem, it did help to clarify and understand. Should I mark this post now?