# How to put the Solarized Theme in TexMaker Editor

Tags: texmaker

I'm trying to change the background of texmaker by using copy-pasting it into the config file but It doesn't change the background as [dawu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/60539/dawu) has it [in his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196020) to the question:

[How can I set a dark theme in TeXstudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/anyone-willing-to-share-his-her-custom-dark-theme-for-texstudio/)

Comment: Welcome! Are you using TeXStudio or TeXmaker?

Comment: So do you have any reason to think it should work for TeXmaker?

Comment: Read the comments down on the link from dawu, who has customized it for TexMaker

Comment: Can you edit your post to replace the current link with `http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196020/`? That will provide a direct link to the relevant answer and should avoid the confusion I had around the TeXStudio/TeXmaker issue. I tried to edit your post to substitute the link myself (I was then going to ask you to confirm it was correct). However, it all went horribly wrong and now I can't :(.

Comment: Oh, I see Community did it. Can you just check it is the correct link?

Answer (score 7):

From MrGer's answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196020/100323

[image: Texmaker with Solarized dark theme]

You can add it at Texmaker's config file `texmaker.ini`, which should located at

- **Linux**: `$HOME/.config/xm1`
- **Windows**: `%APPDATA%/xm1`
- **Mac OS X**: `$HOME/.config/xm1`

Here are the lines with the colors. They need to be replaced at the config file:

```
Color\Background=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\0\0++66\0\0)
Color\Command=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff&&\x8b\x8b\xd2\xd2\0\0)
Color\Comment=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xffllqq\xc4\xc4\0\0)
Color\Highlight=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\a\a66BB\0\0)
Color\Keyword=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\xdc\xdc\x32\x32//\0\0)
Color\KeywordGraphic=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\x85\x85\x99\x99\0\0\0\0)
Color\Line=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\a\a66BB\0\0)
Color\Math=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff**\xa1\xa1\x98\x98\0\0)
Color\NumberGraphic=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\xcb\xcbKK\x16\x16\0\0)
Color\Standard=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\x83\x83\x94\x94\x96\x96\0\0)
Color\Todo=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\xd3\xd3\x36\x36\x82\x82\0\0)
Color\Verbatim=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\xb5\xb5\x89\x89\0\0\0\0)
```

Comment: This did not work for me at the beginning. I opened the file, replaced the lines, saved, started texmaker but nothing changed.

Comment: TO MAKE IT WORK: I opened the file, copied it in a new file, replaced the lines, saved with a different name, started texmaker and then OPTIONS->SettingsFile->Replace Settings File with a New One 

Selected the new file just created, restarted texmaker and voila'.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I've made the same code for solarized light and **Texmaker**:

```
Color\Background=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\xfd\xfd\xf6\xf6\xe3\xe3\0\0)
Color\Command=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff&&\x8b\x8b\xd2\xd2\0\0)
Color\Comment=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\x93\x93\xa1\xa1\xa1\xa1\0\0)
Color\Highlight=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\x93\x93\xa1\xa1\xa1\xa1\0\0)
Color\Keyword=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\xdc\xdc\x32\x32//\0\0)
Color\KeywordGraphic=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\x85\x85\x99\x99\0\0\0\0)
Color\Line=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\xee\xee\xe8\xe8\xd5\xd5\0\0)
Color\Math=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff**\xa1\xa1\x98\x98\0\0)
Color\NumberGraphic=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\xcb\xcbKK\x16\x16\0\0)
Color\Standard=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\x65\x65{{\x83\x83\0\0)
Color\Todo=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\xd3\xd3\x36\x36\x82\x82\0\0)
Color\Verbatim=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\xb5\xb5\x89\x89\0\0\0\0)
```