# Where is .texsprofile in TexStudio Linux?

Tags: texstudio, linux, ide

I'm trying to use a [more stylish dark theme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/anyone-willing-to-share-his-her-custom-dark-theme-for-texstudio) in TexStudio (installed using `apt-get`) on Ubuntu 64-bit. Where can I find `.texsprofile`? All of the other relevant TeX.SX questions deal with Windows or Mac OS.

Comment: You do not need to know the original directory of .texsprofile! Go to option and save your current configuration as a new file somewhere which convenient for you. Copy the dark theme format to replace the current one. Load the edited configuration file and restart your TeXStudio :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.txsprofile` is just a format used to import/export texstudio settings. The current settings are stored in `texstudio.ini`.

See also [FAQ: Where are the settings stored](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-the-settings-stored)