# Dark theme for Texstudio

Tags: texstudio

In follow up to this question:

[How can I set a dark theme in TeXstudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/anyone-willing-to-share-his-her-custom-dark-theme-for-texstudio)

People here are giving their themes to post in a file ".texsprofile". I searched my whole disk for a file with this extension but I could not find it.

Could anyone tell me where exactly this file is hidden or how to change the theme, because my eyes really hurt after some hours of latex..

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome. [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257546/where-is-texsprofile-in-texstudio-linux) should answer your question.

Comment: Launch your texstudio. ->option->save current configuration! Place the ".texsprofile" somewhere you can easily find it. Open the ".texsprofile" with any text editor. Copy the format you found in your link and past it. ->options->load configuration file! Restart your texstudio!

Answer (score 10):

**Edit in 2021:** Since version 3 there (finally) is a built-in dark mode, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/592722/223046).

%% original answer: %%

You can find a step by step explanation on how to set a dark theme for Texstudio
http://www.pauljhurtado.com/latex/texstudio.html
scroll down to section **Dark Color Theme for TeXstudio Editor**

Here is a copy/past of the instructions:

### Dark Color Theme for TeXstudio Editor

Instructions for installing a pre-configured dark theme for the TeXstudio editor:

1. Download a dark color theme:

   1. My dark theme: `Texstudio-dark-Hurtado.txsprofile`
   2. Various examples at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texstudio.
   3. My dark theme plus some editor modifications (e.g. supressed underline of grammar mistakes, etc.): `Texstudio-darkplus-Hurtado.txsprofile`

   Open up the color theme in a text editor (I prefer notepad++).

   Next come the "not-so-user-friendly" steps, so let me walk you through them!

   1. Go to **Options > Save profile...** and save a backup of the current profile to something like `user-default.txsprofile`.

      Do this again, but instead save to a file named something like `custom-dark1.txsprofile`. Note the directory this file is saved it!

      Open `custom-dark1.txsprofile` (or whatever you named it) with a text editor (again, I like notepad++) and scroll to the very bottom which should look like

      ...
      [formats]
      version=1.0

      Note these are the first two lines of the dark theme file you downloaded!

      Copy and paste the contents of the dark them to this section of `custom-dark1.txsprofile` file and save. The [formats] section of `custom-dark1.txsprofile` should now read

      ...
      [formats]
      version=1.0
      data\normal\priority=-1
      data\normal\bold=false
      ...

   Go to **Options > Load profile...** and load the newly edited `custom-dark1.txsprofile`.

   Restart TexStudio and open a file, and you should see the dark themed editor!

   Finally, you can further modify your color scheme by going to **Options > Configure TeXstudio > Syntax Highlighting**

Comment: Link-only answers to external content may eventually rot. It's best to include the essential parts of the answer here (to avoid click-through and preserve content locally) while still providing attribution.

Comment: These steps seems to change only the right panel (editor).
What about all other panels and toolbar colors?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You can add the follow code in  your template. (read this if you have same problem to find your original template    [How can I set a dark theme in TeXstudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/anyone-willing-to-share-his-her-custom-dark-theme-for-texstudio)). Copy che original theme, rename it and add this code:

```
[formats]
version=1.0
data\normal\priority=-1
data\normal\bold=false
data\normal\italic=false
data\normal\overline=false
data\normal\underline=false
data\normal\strikeout=false
data\normal\waveUnderline=false
data\normal\foreground=#C9C38D
data\normal\fontFamily=
data\normal\pointSize=0
data\background\priority=-1
data\background\bold=false
data\background\italic=false
data\background\overline=false
data\background\underline=false
data\background\strikeout=false
data\background\waveUnderline=false
data\background\background=#1C1C1C
data\background\fontFamily=
data\background\pointSize=0
data\commentTodo\priority=-1
data\commentTodo\bold=false
data\commentTodo\italic=false
data\commentTodo\overline=false
data\commentTodo\underline=false
data\commentTodo\strikeout=false
data\commentTodo\waveUnderline=false
data\commentTodo\foreground=#848484
data\commentTodo\fontFamily=
data\commentTodo\pointSize=0
data\comment\priority=-1
data\comment\bold=false
data\comment\italic=false
data\comment\overline=false
data\comment\underline=false
data\comment\strikeout=false
data\comment\waveUnderline=false
data\comment\foreground=#848484
data\comment\fontFamily=
data\comment\pointSize=0
data\keyword\priority=-1
data\keyword\bold=false
data\keyword\italic=false
data\keyword\overline=false
data\keyword\underline=false
data\keyword\strikeout=false
data\keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\keyword\foreground=#66A7AF
data\keyword\fontFamily=
data\keyword\pointSize=0
data\extra-keyword\priority=-1
data\extra-keyword\bold=true
data\extra-keyword\italic=false
data\extra-keyword\overline=false
data\extra-keyword\underline=false
data\extra-keyword\strikeout=false
data\extra-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\extra-keyword\foreground=#66A7AF
data\extra-keyword\fontFamily=
data\extra-keyword\pointSize=0
data\math-keyword\priority=-1
data\math-keyword\bold=false
data\math-keyword\italic=false
data\math-keyword\overline=false
data\math-keyword\underline=false
data\math-keyword\strikeout=false
data\math-keyword\waveUnderline=false
data\math-keyword\foreground=#66A7AF
data\math-keyword\fontFamily=
data\math-keyword\pointSize=0
data\link\priority=-1
data\link\bold=false
data\link\italic=false
data\link\overline=false
data\link\underline=true
data\link\strikeout=false
data\link\waveUnderline=false
data\link\fontFamily=
data\link\pointSize=0
data\align-ampersand\priority=-1
data\align-ampersand\bold=true
data\align-ampersand\italic=false
data\align-ampersand\overline=false
data\align-ampersand\underline=false
data\align-ampersand\strikeout=false
data\align-ampersand\waveUnderline=false
data\align-ampersand\foreground=#66A7AF
data\align-ampersand\fontFamily=
data\align-ampersand\pointSize=0
data\verbatim\priority=-1
data\verbatim\bold=false
data\verbatim\italic=false
data\verbatim\overline=false
data\verbatim\underline=false
data\verbatim\strikeout=false
data\verbatim\waveUnderline=false
data\verbatim\fontFamily=
data\verbatim\pointSize=0
data\sweave\priority=-1
data\sweave\bold=false
data\sweave\italic=false
data\sweave\overline=false
data\sweave\underline=false
data\sweave\strikeout=false
data\sweave\waveUnderline=false
data\sweave\fontFamily=
data\sweave\pointSize=0
data\picture\priority=-1
data\picture\bold=false
data\picture\italic=false
data\picture\overline=false
data\picture\underline=false
data\picture\strikeout=false
data\picture\waveUnderline=false
data\picture\foreground=#66A7AF
data\picture\fontFamily=
data\picture\pointSize=0
data\numbers\priority=-1
data\numbers\bold=false
data\numbers\italic=false
data\numbers\overline=false
data\numbers\underline=false
data\numbers\strikeout=false
data\numbers\waveUnderline=false
data\numbers\foreground=#66A7AF
data\numbers\fontFamily=
data\numbers\pointSize=0
data\math-delimiter\priority=-1
data\math-delimiter\bold=true
data\math-delimiter\italic=false
data\math-delimiter\overline=false
data\math-delimiter\underline=false
data\math-delimiter\strikeout=false
data\math-delimiter\waveUnderline=false
data\math-delimiter\foreground=#66A7AF
data\math-delimiter\fontFamily=
data\math-delimiter\pointSize=0
data\text\priority=-1
data\text\bold=false
data\text\italic=false
data\text\overline=false
data\text\underline=false
data\text\strikeout=false
data\text\waveUnderline=false
data\text\fontFamily=
data\text\pointSize=0
data\escapeseq\priority=-1
data\escapeseq\bold=false
data\escapeseq\italic=false
data\escapeseq\overline=false
data\escapeseq\underline=false
data\escapeseq\strikeout=false
data\escapeseq\waveUnderline=false
data\escapeseq\fontFamily=
data\escapeseq\pointSize=0
data\latexSyntaxMistake\priority=-1
data\latexSyntaxMistake\bold=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\italic=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\overline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\underline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\strikeout=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\waveUnderline=false
data\latexSyntaxMistake\fontFamily=
data\latexSyntaxMistake\pointSize=0
data\environment\priority=-1
data\environment\bold=false
data\environment\italic=false
data\environment\overline=false
data\environment\underline=false
data\environment\strikeout=false
data\environment\waveUnderline=false
data\environment\foreground=#b58900
data\environment\fontFamily=
data\environment\pointSize=0
data\structure\priority=-1
data\structure\bold=true
data\structure\italic=false
data\structure\overline=false
data\structure\underline=false
data\structure\strikeout=false
data\structure\waveUnderline=false
data\structure\fontFamily=
data\structure\pointSize=0
data\current\priority=-1
data\current\bold=false
data\current\italic=false
data\current\overline=false
data\current\underline=false
data\current\strikeout=false
data\current\waveUnderline=false
data\current\background=#292929
data\current\fontFamily=
data\current\pointSize=0
```