# Where should I get the TexStudio theme similar to midnight black in Winedit?

Tags: texstudio

I am new to TeX.

Where can I get the TexStudio theme similar to midnight black in Winedit?

[image]

Comment: Hi @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes and welcome to TeX-SE.
Possible duplicate of a duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275534/140133
Original: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texstudio
Check: https://github.com/pmaroco/dark-texstudio and 
https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-the-settings-stored.

Comment: Thank you very much.