# TeXStudio doesn't recognize self-defined commands in external file

Tags: tables, errors, texstudio, external-files

I'd like to define some tables as commands (MWE) in an external .tex file,
because there are a lot of settings for them. This external file gets included in the main document by the `\input{}` command. Using my pre-defined commands is no problem. TeXStudio is able to compile the main document and also gives an output. The problem is, that TeXStudio doesn't recognize the `\hline` command and the `&` separator for tables inside my self-defined table (the editor says there are table commands outside of table environment). Also, if only the main document is opened in the editor (without the myTemplate file), 
the `\mytable{}` and `\lb` commands I defined in the external document are not recognized.

[image]

Is there a way to make this red highlighting disappear
without simply deactivating the syntax-highlighting? I got some help from here: [TeXStudio doesn't recognize some commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47493/texstudio-doesnt-recognize-some-commands), because I've had the same Problem with other commands before. Though, These commands were from packages I got from ctan, so no self-defined commands.

I'm not sure if this problem is reproducable for you, but here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\input{myTemplate.tex}

\begin{document} 

\mytable{
%% \hline A & B & C & D & E \\ \hline
a & b1 \lb b2 \lb b3 & c1 \lb c2 \lb c3 & d & e \\ \hline
& & & & \\ \hline
& & & & \\ \hline   
}

\end{document}
```

And the myTemplate file:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} 

\newcommand{\mytable}[1]{%
\begin{center}
    \rowcolors{1}{white}{pink}
    \begin{tabular}{| M{.2\textwidth} | M{.15\textwidth} | M{.1\textwidth} | M{.2\textwidth} | M{.2\textwidth} | M{.15\textwidth}|} \hline
    A & B & C & D & E \\ \hline
    #1
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}%
}

\newcommand{\lb}{\linebreak}
```

Comment: it won't affect your highlighting but why have you got `\begin{table}` in your definition of `\mytable`? as you haven't got a caption it would be better and simpler just to use `tabular`. Also you are missing `%` after the `{` and after `\end{tabular}`

Comment: In the real document the table should have alternating rowcolors. So there is a `rowcolors` command, which must be put inside a table environment, I think ... But I added this Information and also the `%`, thanks for the advice!

Comment: `\rowcolors` doesn't require `table`

Comment: If I place `\rowcolors` outside a table environment all tables would get these rowcolors, wouldn't they? But I'd like to have this setting only in this particular kind of tables - is this possible without putting it inside the `table` environment?

Comment: you could use `center` environment or just `{..}`  or any other group, it is nothing to do with `table`

Comment: Alright, I replaced `table` with `center` now, thank you! Just out of curiosity: Why is using another group better than using `table`?

Comment: Related: [In TeXstudio, how to change the (syntax highlighting) type of a command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300331/in-texstudio-how-to-change-the-syntax-highlighting-type-of-a-command/300389#300389) -> you want here your own macro to be recognized as type *"table"*, don't you?

Comment: @kanra it's easier to control the spacing and almost everything that the table environment is designed to do isn't needed here, but it was on;y a side comment as I can't help with your main question as I have never used texstudio:-)

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to selectively switch of parts of the syntax checking. It's also not possible to make the parser accept table-like behavior in arguments.

However, you could define your own table environment:

```
\newenvironment{mytable}{%
    \begin{center}
        \rowcolors{1}{white}{pink}
        \begin{tabular}{| M{.2\textwidth} | M{.15\textwidth} | M{.1\textwidth} | M{.2\textwidth} | M{.2\textwidth} | M{.15\textwidth}|}     \hline
            A & B & C & D & E \\ \hline
}{\end{tabular}\end{center}}
```

in a custom .cwl declare that environment to be tabular-like:

```
\begin{mytable}#\tabular
\end{mytable}
```

and use it in your document:

```
\begin{mytable}
%% \hline A & B & C & D & E \\ \hline
a & b1 \lb b2 \lb b3 & c1 \lb c2 \lb c3 & d & e \\ \hline
& & & & \\ \hline
& & & & \\ \hline   
\end{mytable}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I defined the `newenvironment` in the myTemplate.tex. Then I created a .cwl file (where the other .cwl files are stored) containing the suggested lines and used the `mytable` Environment in my main document. In Addition, I tried the same with an .sty file instead of a .tex file. Also, I activated the myTemplate.cwl in the completion section of the TeXStudio configurations. Though, the `&` and `\hline` are still said to be tabular commands outside of table Environment. For the `\end{}` command it says "command not recognized". Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Just from what you are writing, it should work. Of course, I cannot see your setup. Try fist with a minimal document in a single file that defines and uses the envrionment.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I have three files:

- MySty.sty (here defined some new commands, enviroments, etc),
- print.tex

```
        \documentclass[12pt]{article}
        \usepackage{MyStyle.sty}

        \begin{document}
                \input{1.tex}
                \input{2.tex}
                .............
        \end{document}
```

- 1.tex (here my custom commands not recognized by TeXStudio)

I just changed `\usepackage{MyStyle.sty}` to `\input{MyStyle.sty}`.
And now all project succesly compiling and there's no unrecognizing highlighting in all my files.

Comment: In the question `\input` was already used, and not `\usepackage`, so this is not really an answer to the question.