# Aligning Text in Enumerate Environments within TeXMaker

Tags: texmaker

I don’t really know how to phrase this question, so I am sorry if I am a bit meander-y. This question pertains to the formatting side of typesetting in LaTeX, not the compiling side.

I am currently self-studying a textbook on Information Theory. While reading I am taking notes in LaTeX, using TeXMaker. I am a big fan of using bullet-points/lists. To do so, I use the enumerate/itemize environments. I also like to keep my code tidy, using indentation. When I start a list environment, I like to have all my `\item`s below my `\begin{enumerate}`, indented exactly once.

The problem with this is that whenever the text pertaining to a specific `\item` is longer than one line, it wraps around, and starts from the very left of the screen.  See the image below to understand this better.

[image]

One solution I have tried to amend this, is to simply indent the text that has wrapped around.

However, this causes a problem whenever I find a typo in something I have previously typed. At that point, the extra text that I add sometimes causes the text to wrap at a different point, making the additional tabs to appear in the `\item` text, as shown below.

[image]

My question is, is there any way to force the text to align below the `\begin{enumerate}`  tabbed in exactly once, so that I don’t have to deal with this every time I change something in my text. I know this might seem like minutia, but it’s the small things that really bother me.

I would have added more pictures to make this clearer, however due to my low reputation I can't.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, your question is about how the text in your *source* document is formatted, right? You're not asking about how to format the *output* of a list in the PDF.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am happy with how the list appears in the PDF, but I would like my source text to be more orderly.

Comment: as a comparison emacs wraps the source to look like this http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31223080#31223080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeXstudio is in may ways quite similar to TeXMaker, but it wraps its lines so that they are aliged to the item, regardless how far indented this is.

[image]

In case line wrapping is not enables, this can be done in the `Preferences->Adv. Editor->Line Wrapping`.

Comment: How easy is it to transfer text from TeXMaker to TeXstudio? I have a couple thousand lines of notes, and changing compiler could take a while.

Comment: @GrancescoFrechi Simple. `.tex` files are just plain text files. You're changing the editor not the compiler. So get TeXStudio, and then make that the default application for opening `.tex` files. (How to do this will depend on your operating system.)

Comment: I meant more with regards to the formatting. From what I gathered from samcarter's answer, the two compilers have different spacing rules. Will my text from TexMaker be properly transferred, or will it be oddly spaced?

Comment: @GrancescoFrechi Depends. As TeXStudio once was a fork of TeXMaker, the overall look, feel and handling are very similar. I normally do not apply any formatting to my code besides indention and TeXStudio displays everything nice and clearly. But if you already added a lot of formatting to your code, I don't know how TeXStudio will react - just try out and see yourself.

Comment: @GrancescoFrechi From your images, I guess you use a pretty big width for one tab, but things like this can all be adjusted in TeXStudio. Concerning your dark colour scheme, there are questions on this site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126083/36296

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for your answers :)

Comment: @GrancescoFrechi You're welcome! Just give it a try :)