# Cannot obtain proper command highlighting with Texstudio and tex.qnfa

Tags: texstudio, editors, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to obtain a custom highlighting for the \xnote command in TexStudio editor, and I'm following these [instructions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328283/41963), but when I add the lines to tex.qnfa as suggested it highlights the entire text after the first "\xnote": seems like it doesn't recognize the end of the command.

I would ask if you can indicate if there is an error with the lines that I'm adding:

```
<context id="comment/todocmd" format="commentTodo">
     ...
     <start parenthesis="todo:open" prenthesisweight="12">\\xnote\{</start>
     ...
</context>
```

Moreover I would like to use this highlight feature in combination with my color scheme, but if I use tex.qnfa it replaces my personal .txs profile setting the standard colours, so I would ask how to do to mantain my color scheme while using tex.qnfa.

Comment: Maybe it is better to ask this question here https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907840/

Comment: yes, for example I can have \xnote{mynote}, where in a separate file I write the note content with \xnotecontent{mynote}{the content of the note}. I would only highlight \xnote{mynote}, in order to better focus it in the editor

Comment: You're leaving out the part you are asking about?!? What's your `<stop>` command? Moreover, if you just want `\xnote` to behave like `\todo`, you can define this in a cwl file.

See [manual: cwl description](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION) and
[FAQ: What are cwl files good for and how do they work](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#what-are-cwl-files-good-for-and-how-do-they-work)

Comment: So I have to create a .cwl file called xnote.cwl and write inside it \xnote{arg1}D? Is that correct?