# How can I highlight code in the TeXStudio editor?

Tags: texstudio

If you make a todo-comment, e.g. %XX, it will be highlighted green (in my case).

Can I manually highlight other code? For instance, it would be a help to me if I could highlight the section and subsection title, so I could easiler navigate and keep an over view.

Comment: Which editor are you talking about?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You only want to highlight code in the editor and not in the pdf file?

Comment: Did you made a research before posting? "highlight code" gives me 43 pages of answers in this file, your question must have been answered somewhere. And the answer depends on the editor, so please search "highlight code myeditor".

Comment: @TeXnician: Sorry, I forgot that. I am using TexStudio

Comment: @Bobyandbob: yes, that's right. Just as a help to maintain the overview

Comment: @sztruks: Thanks for your comment. I have - of course - searched for a solution before asking. To my understanding, other post relate to how you by coding, can highlight text. If you have seen a thread regarding my question, I would appreciate a link.

Comment: @sztruks, I just checked again. I don't find any regarding the question I am posing. But I admit, not finding a relevant answer or even a thread, might be due to my lack of knowledge. any help here is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help ? :  https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#how-does-the-custom-highlighting-work

Comment: I have tried to insert a manipulated snipet of code to illustrate. But I can not get it to represent the text as code. Is there a way to insert a piece of "code" - typed in e.g. libreoffice?

Comment: @jbahn have a look into your texstudio perferences. In the tab "adv. editor" you can find a possibility to adjust which regex is used to search for todo commands. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE56x.png

Comment: @samcarter, I don't seem to have that option [url=http://i.imgur.com/GQcmHo2.png]
  [img]http://imgur.com/GQcmHo2l.png[/img]
[/url]

Comment: @jbahn Which version of Texstudio do you have? Do you have "show advanced options" activated?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeXstudio does highlight quite a lot different things.

1. You can adapt the colors for known formats at `Options -> Syntax Highlighting`. For sections use `Basic Highlighting -> structure`.
2. For modifying which %TODO-like commands are matched, adapt `Options -> Advanced Editor -> Structure Panel -> Regular expression for TODO comment.
3. There are a number of further options which control highlighting of relevant information such as undefined commands.
4. If you want even more control, you can modify the [Language Definition](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#LANGUAGEDEF). Be sure to understand the implications. You can find an example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328283/24770).