# How can I have the dark theme in TexMaker?

Tags: texmaker

I am beginning in TexMaker and I want to change into the dark mod (direct request of my eyes).

In the configurations, I clicked on the dark theme button but nothing changed, even by restarting the program. Any indication guys ?

Moreover I tried to change the .init file, but after a restart, the file turned like it was before.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: After the restart did you try opening a file to edit.   That is when the dark theme is used (in the edit window) not the entire texmaker window.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: [Related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108315/64454) if you decide to switch to [TeXstudio](http://www.texstudio.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If R. Schumacher's comment didn't help out and your Texmaker is still not in the dark theme, you can just fill in the colours yourself, because (as far as I can tell) the dark theme button just changes the hexadecimal values. I'll list them here for you:

- Background: #0c1021
- Current line: #131727
- Highlighted line: #FF0000
- Text: #f8f8f8
- Comment: #aeaeae
- Math: #61ce3c
- LaTeX command: #8da6ce
- Structure: #fadd2d
- Verbatim: #e6a252
- Todo: #FF6400
- Graphic keywords: #f47bda
- Graphic Numbers: #660066

Hope this helps, because I can't really work with a white background myself for a long time so I know the pain!

Answer (score 0):

you need to press "Enter" after you make the changes, they do not have an "Apply" button in the dialogue box.

Answer (score 0):

I usually try not to mess with the settings. Instead of this on my Windows computer, I use color filter settings. Select inverted filter and use the "win + ctrl + C" shortcut to invert the colors.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way: go to --> preferences --> editor settings --> select dark mode, press ok!!
[image: for reference, see the image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!