# Gummi night mode preview?

Tags: texstudio, gummi, live-preview

What I'm looking for is a simple latex editor with autocompletion capabilities, live preview, and a night mode which applies to both the code *and* live preview (so that one can make the preview background be dark and the text light).

I get almost all of these with gummi, which I've been using for years, except now I'm trying to reduce eye strain, and I haven't been able to find a way to make gummi's live preview turn into night mode. I looked at TeXStudio, which also seems to have all the other features (though is kind of unnecessarily burdened with stuff I don't use), but again no luck with night-mode preview.

Comment: You have the option to change the colour scheme in TeXstudio. Check this out: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108599/117534

Comment: I had tried the exact theme you pointed me to, but it doesn't change the preview background

Comment: Are you talking about the PDF? For that, you'd have to change the document. (I don't know how gummi's preview works - maybe it doesn't compile and does something else.)

Comment: You mean the PDF? I'm not too sure of the possibilities in that regard then. Apart from actually changing the background colour of your PDF file through hardcoding into your TeX code.

Comment: Oh, I guess you're right I can change it from the TeX code. That's slightly annoying but I think it will have to do for now! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeXstudio supports inverting the colors of the pdf.

Changing the option is only possible in the menu of windowed viewer: `Configure -> Invert Colors`. You can also combine it with `Grayscale` if you want. The options stays active also when you switch back to the embedded viewer.

Answer (score 1):

One can get close to the nightly mode using following two tricks.

1. Go to Edit -> Preferences -> Fonts and Colors and select **Cobalt theme** which is closer to night mode.
2. Add following code to just before `\begin{document}` tag:

   ```
   \usepackage{xcolor}  
   \pagecolor[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}  
   \color[rgb]{1,1,1}
   ```

The above code might perform poorly for colored content, but performs very well for grayscale pdf.

Comment: P.S. - Opened an issue for a nightly theme - https://github.com/alexandervdm/gummi/issues/75

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!