# Textstudio menu color

Tags: texstudio

How can I make the background color of the menu gray in texstudio?
original:
[image]

I want this:
[image]

Updated: (Don't the gray parts over there also change?)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go Options -> Configure TeXstudio. Under the "General" tab, choose the "Modern" Color scheme.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I added one more image.

Comment: @cufcuf No, the area where the line numbers are clearly doesn't change. I've never looked into customizing the look of TeXstudio, so this is just based on a minute of searching: it looks like it's possible to customize the look with CSS, perhaps that can be useful: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/45#issuecomment-368301279 There are also other "dark themes", but it's not clear to me if that applies only to the text area or the rest of the UI: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108315/. Don't ask me about details though (I don't know them), probably better to post a new question.

Comment: thanks man you are right