# Problems with dark theme in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, themes

The accepted answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texstudio) suggests to go *Options*, *Configure TeXstudio...*, *General*, *Style*, and afterwards *Adwaita Dark*. However, when I click on *Style*, I only have these three options:

- Windows
- Fusion
- default

Is there any reason why I'm not seeing the Adwaita Dark option? I'm using TeXstudio with Ubuntu.

Comment: Is your version up to date?

Answer (score 1):

Its a somewhat old question, but it was a problem I was running into with arch linux as well. Hence I'm posting this because I hope it can help someone else if the OP has already fixed the issue. I'm also only posting this as an answer because I don't have enough reputation to comment.

TexStudio is a Qt6 application, so if you haven't by any chance installed the package "adwaita-qt6" (available at aur, but perhaps ubuntu has a similar package at its repos) the adwaita themes wont show up as possible themes on TexStudio options. Now, if you have the flatpak version of TexStudio, these options will show up regardless of either you have installed the package I mentioned or not.