# TeXstudio Find box gets partially invisible when starting to enter a search term

Tags: texstudio, box, find

I have just installed TeXstudio + MiKTeX on Windows 10 and am trying to use Find & Replace. After I have entered the second or third symbol (no pattern found, it can go either way), the lower part of the Find box becomes invisible. The three attached images show my steps in trying to enter "qwerty". The empty Find box first; then a "q" letter is added, and everything is still fine; and then I'm adding "w".

Please advise.

[image]

Comment: As a workaround, you could try [a different skin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108315). [This issue on TeXstudio's tracker](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1888) seems to be relevant.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel
Skin, yes! Thank you, problem solved